# Is this number an integer power of -2?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, integer

There are [clever ways](/q/17456) of determining whether a number is a power of 2.  That's no longer an interesting problem, so let's determine whether a given integer is an integer power of **-2**.  For example:

```
-2 => yes: (-2)¹
-1 => no
0 => no
1 => yes: (-2)⁰
2 => no
3 => no
4 => yes: (-2)²
```

### Rules

- You may write a [program or a function](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419) and use any of the [standard methods](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) of receiving input and providing output.
- Your input is a single integer, and output must be a truthy value if the integer is an integer power of -2, and a falsy value otherwise.  No other output (e.g. warning messages) is permitted.
- The usual integer overflow rules apply: your solution must be able to work for arbitrarily large integers in a hypothetical (or perhaps real) version of your language in which all integers are unbounded by default, but if your program fails in practice due to the implementation not supporting integers that large, that doesn't invalidate the solution.
- You may use any [programming language](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2028), but note that these [loopholes](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/) are forbidden by default.

### Winning condition

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest: the answer which has the fewest bytes (in your chosen encoding) is the winner.

Comment: `2 => no` shouldn't this be yes?

Comment: @KritixiLithos I don't see why it should. There is no integer `i` such that `(-2)^i = 2`

Comment: Are the exponents positive or `-0.5` should be valid since it's   *2^(-1)*.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, Since inputs are always *integer values*, a negative exponent won't be required (or possible).

Comment: @Fatalize But literally `(-2)^i` might be 2...

Comment: @SIGSEGV maybe whereas `i` is not natural

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, I think SIGSEGV was being facetious, as Fatalize clearly wrote "integer `i`".  It's just a play on *i* being the standard imaginary number.  Don't get too serious about that!

Comment: @Fatalize silly me, I thought the challenge asked for a power of 2 instead

Comment: How many bits is the input integer?

Comment: @Jason, as many as supported/natural in your language - see the third rule.  And it's [tag:code-golf] because it needs an *objective* winning criterion to be on-topic here - "a pleasing solution" doesn't cut it (though I do like the Mathematica answer - that surprised me).

Comment: One thing you could have done, which is reminiscent of some of the challenge contests we used to have in college, is limit the solution to a set of *operations*, e.g. bit shifts, bitwise operators, addition/subtraction/multiplication/division or something. And limit it to a certain language (most popular languages are similar in this regard). *Then* make it code-golf. Now *that* would have been proper treatment of this otherwise really great challenge.

Comment: @TobySpeight I've proposed an alternate version of this challenge [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115573/is-this-number-an-exact-power-of-2-hard-mode).

Answer (score 29):

### Mathematica, 22 bytes

```
EvenQ@Log2@Max[#,-2#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#C07NSU0uiQ5KzEtPjdY1NDDQAeJYnf@uZal5gQ4@@elGDr6JFdHKOrpGyrFq/2MV9PUVAooy80r@AwA) (Using Mathics instead, where this solution also works.)

I tried to find a solution with bitwise operators for a while, and while one definitely exists, I ended up finding something which is probably simpler:

- `Max[#,-2#]` multiplies the input by **-2** if it's negative. Multiplying by another factor of **-2** doesn't change whether the value is a power of **-2** or not. But now all odd powers of **-2** have been turned into even powers of **-2**.
- But even powers of **-2** are also even powers of **2**, so we can use a simple `Log2@...` and check if the result is an integer (to check whether it's a power of **2**). This already saves two bytes over `Log[4,...]` (another way to look at even powers of **-2**).
- As an added bonus, checking whether a value is an even integer is shorter than just checking whether it's an integer: we can save three more bytes by using `EvenQ` instead of `IntegerQ`.

Comment: Does it help to consider that even powers of -2 are integer powers of 4?  I like the idea of multiplying by -2 to get everything positive - though disappointed to see no bit-twiddling so far.

Comment: @TobySpeight Treating them as powers of 2 actually saves 5 bytes. I used powers of 4 at first, but `Log[4,...]` is longer than `Log2@...` and `IntegerQ` is longer than `EvenQ`.

Answer (score 19):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
æḟ-2=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ARkA5v//w6bhuJ8tMj3/LTlyOcK1xbzDh@KCrEf/)

#### How it works

```
æḟ-2=  Main link. Argument: n

æḟ-2   Round n towards 0 to the nearest power of -2.
    =  Test if the result is equal to n.
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
b-2S⁼1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@5@kaxT8qHGP4f///3WNAA)

This is based on how Jelly converts an integer *N* to any arbitrary base *B*, doing so by converting *N* to an array, in which each integer is a digit *d* of (*N*)<sub>*B*</sub>, which can have a value 0≤*V<sub>d</sub>*<*B*. Here, we will 0-index digits from the right, so every digit adds *V<sub>d</sub>B<sup>d</sup>* to form *N*. *V<sub>d</sub>*<*B*⇔*V<sub>d</sub>B<sup>d</sup>*<*BB<sup>d</sup>*=*B*<sup>*d*+1</sup>, therefore every possible *N* has only one unique representation, if we ignore leading 0s in (*N*)<sub>*B*</sub>.

Here, *d*=input, *B*=-2. *N*=*B<sup>d</sup>*=1*B<sup>d</sup>*=*V<sub>d</sub>B<sup>d</sup>*⇔1=*V<sub>d</sub>*⇔*V<sub>d</sub>*=1, and, since we're not adding any other multiples of powers of *B*, every other *V* would be 0. Right now, the array should be a 1 concatenated with *d* 0s. Since Jelly 1-indexes from the left, we should check whether the array's 1st element is 1, and all other elements are 0.

Hmm... all good, right? No? What's going on? Oh yeah, I have a better idea! First, let's take the sum of all of the integers in the array, treating it as if it was an integer array and not a number in base -2. If it is 1, it means that there is only one 1, and all other integers are 0. Since there can't be leading zeroes, except in the case of 0<sub>-2</sub> (where the sum would be 0≠1 anyways), the 1st integer must be non-zero. The only non-zero integer in the array is the 1, so it must be the first one. Therefore, this is the only case that the sum of all of the integers in the array would be 1, because the smallest possible sum of a pair of positive integers is Σ{1,1}=2, since the smallest positive integer is 1. Every integer in a base representation is non-negative, so the only way the sum is 1 is to only have one 1, and all other integers are 0. Therefore, we can just check if the sum of all of the integers in the array is 1.

Here is what the code does:

```
b-2S⁼1 Main link. Arguments: d
b-2    Convert d to base -2.
   S   Take the sum.
    ⁼1 Check if the sum is equal to 1.
```

Comment: Phew, that explanation took time to write...

Comment: I'd hate to see what an explanation for a long program would look like then...

Comment: @boboquack Here I am explaining why I use the base conversion stuff. I don't think explanation for long programs would be this long. A post can contain up to 30000 markdown characters, and explanations for longer programs would be more terse anyways. Also, I have read much longer explanations, and they are not that boring.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @ovs.*

```python
def g(x):
 while x%-2==0!=x:x/=-2
 return x==1
```

Function with usage:

```python
g(4) # put your number between the brackets
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFdo0LTikuhPCMzJ1WhQlXXyNbWQNG2wqpC31bXiEuhKLWktChPocLW1vB/QVFmXglQg4nmfwA)

Comment: `print g(8)` prints `False`

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista shouldn't it?

Comment: sorry, my example was a bad one, `print g(4)` does the same

Comment: Wait, there is a small error, fixing it shortly

Comment: I've put a `;` instead of a newline... sorry for that. Fixed @FelipeNardiBatista

Comment: Can you not use `x%2<1:x/=-2`?

Comment: Oh yes, @Neil. Golfing skills are quite hard to get

Comment: @Neil It actually does not work (do not know why?) using my python 3.6 interpreter... strange... It seems like there is an infinite loop, because when I end the program, it throws `KeyboardInterrupt` on the line with the `while`

Comment: it's because `-9%-2` returns `-1` in both versions of python

Comment: but i think you could do `x%-2+1`

Comment: This doesn't work for `0`. You'd need `while x and ...`

Comment: @mbomb007 fixed

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFdo0LTikuhPCMzJ1WhQlXXyNbWQNG2wqpC31bXiEuhKLWktChPocLW1vB/QVFmXglQg4nmfwA)

Comment: @ovs I'm surprised someone golfed it down after 2 months, but thanks :))

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>98</s> 50 bytes

```python
lambda x:x*(x&-x==abs(x))*((x<0)^x.bit_length()&1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#BcFLDkAwEADQq8yKGUp8dqI3aUgbyiSUVBdz@3rPa5Mve7vNgkxSoRSNaG3dh0JUIcrc0SKt47ReezjSiVT0lP0TgYEDSLTh2LEZBzUOdU8TvJFDAlalSaXyyJR/)

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), <strike>37 28</strike> 24 bytes

```
f=x=>!x|x%2?x==1:f(x/-2)
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

```js
f=x=>!x|x%2?x==1:f(x/-2)

console.log(f(-2));
console.log(f(-1));
console.log(f(0));
console.log(f(1));
console.log(f(2));
console.log(f(3));
console.log(f(4));
```

Comment: Why do I see some errors (before the true/false values) when I click on "Run code snippet"?

Comment: @numbermaniac I'm not sure, maybe you're using a browser that doesn't fully support ES6?

Comment: Welp, refreshed and tried again, no errors. Not sure what happened the first time.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n==1or n!=n%2<f(n/-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcvRCkAwAAXQZ77ieli2sjSKkvmXiUlxafj@4fXUid5ubh8nB3a01hwBzCxF1XvJUlcq@p@wEsFxmaU2TWFa1aXJGVbeyEX9QA8QVw4ByQJfVCq@)

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
Y(IÄÝm¹å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x@p4Xm45fDc3EM7Dy/9/9/QDAA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/B@pUXm45fDc3MrDS/9XKh3eb6VweL@Szn9dCy5dEy5dIy5dQy4DLkMuIy5jLhMuQzMA)

**Explanation**

```
Y(         # push -2
  IÄÝ      # push range [0 ... abs(input)]
     m     # element-wise power
      ¹å   # check if input is in the resulting list
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @KritixiLithos: Seems like someone has downvoted all golfing languages.

Comment: Noticed that too. Although I haven't been around PPCG for long, I've learned that creative and interesting solutions in standard languages are far more appreciated than 3-byte solutions in golfing languages. However, there are some people who (unfortunately) downvote very creative solutions in golfing languages, simply because they think everything is built-in, and don't understand how good the algorithms (although written in golfing languges) are. +1 for the incredible solution @Emigna

Comment: `ÄLY(småO` for 8. `Y(sÄLm¢Z` for 8... Nevermind, all 8.

Answer (score 10):

## Excel, <s>40</s> 36 bytes

<sup><sup>Saved 4 bytes by CallumDA</sup></sup>

Excel can certainly do it but correcting errors adds 11 bytes

```
=IFERROR(-2^IMREAL(IMLOG2(A1)),1)=A1
```

Input is in cell `A1`. Output is `TRUE` or `FALSE`

If it was allowed to return either `FALSE` or `#NUM!` error for false values, it would be only 25 bytes:

```
=-2^IMREAL(IMLOG2(A1))=A1
```

Comment: Heres a small improvement: `=IFERROR(-2^IMREAL(IMLOG2(A1)),1)=A1`

Comment: @CallumDA Thanks! I tried to figure a way to use the complex number functions but everything I came up with was longer.

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>34</s> 29 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n%2?n==1:f(n?n/-2:2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs82T9XIPs/W1tAKyLfP09c1sjLStK79n5uYmaehyVXNpaBQUJSZV5KmoaSaEpOnpJOmoWuhqWmNTdwEh7gRDnFD7OIG2IVxqMZhuDF2YRxOxOEjQzOQeC3X/695@brJickZqQA)

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
2_y|:q^m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28UX1ljVRiX@/@/rgUA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/hvFF9ZY1UYl/vfJeS/rhGXriGXAZchlxGXMZcJAA).

#### How it works

Consider input `-8` as an example

```
2_    % Push -2
      % STACK: -2
y     % Implicit input. Duplicate from below
      % STACK: -8, -2, -8
|     % Absolute value
      % STACK: -8, -2, 8
:     % Range
      % STACK: -8, -2, [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
q     % Subtract 1, element-wise
      % STACK: -8, -2, [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
^     % Power, element-wise
      % STACK: -8, [1 -2 4 -8 16 -32 64 -128]
m     % Ismember. Implicit display
      % STACK: 1
```

Comment: If I understand your explanation correctly, then given input `n`, this creates an array of size `n` as an intermediate step.  Good job that efficiency is not a criterion here!

Comment: @Toby Of course! This is code golf, who cares about efficiency? :-D

Answer (score 8):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
@(n)any((-2).^(0:abs(n))==n)
```

This defines an anonymous function. The approach is similar to that in my MATL answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaeZmFepoaFrpKkXp2FglZhUDBTStLXN0/yfpmCrkJhXbM2VBpLWUQBShmDKAExC2BAJYzBpovkfAA)

Answer (score 8):

## Regex (ECMAScript / Java), <s>38</s> <s>37</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
\b(?=(^|x))((x*)\3\3(?=\3$))*x\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89b8IwGIT/CrUQvG/SmARQVWEMUweGdmjHppUMmMStcSzbQMrHb0@ToVKXG@453em@xFH4jVM2JN6qrXT7ynzLn8ZxI0@9V1k81RbgzBejqMnXsOTwea0RAeoI80k@aZ180keM6jzrN9HojDRUb8EpUwBSr9VGwsN9MkVknqfsVCotATR3Umy1MhIQ77g5aI2XgmvqrVYBhpQOkakdgOEF1dIUocTF@HpV/kW8gOJWOC9XJkDxnn4g/gH5H5hFtsxmHcZQuupEVuYotNr2nDCFnPVIrNmucsDUnEum4hi7QVDzdEkSMiMEY1IT6qSVIsCzCCUVaw@q7aN7ETYlOMSLHwxsezZA9y9j9hB8cG2I3W5NMk6nj5R2@gs) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNtT9swEP7Or7hFTLXb4iWwT5gIbdMmTRrbBB@bTnISpzE4TmY7NMD47d05zQZIRFHO9@Ln7p67XItbcXRd3uxU07XWwzXqTLVszuG5pfdKv2qzciMH9Bx0fa5VAYUWzsGFUAYeYLI5LzyK21aV0KCHXHmrzAaE3bjVmoKvbbt18HkoZOdVizcPAL4oLaFKjdyORxKxoi0lQ39E@ce@qqSV5aUUpbSQj2EvjeTfzUmtKOVTXrf0fFsHfEJcmmMPovymjCSUvklNrzVVFXFM/u6FdiR6N5/PI0ofXobuEQjxrwI8IIL/j4AA7xAhx7gb7hbpLDOzID1/3NsefwrvpTVg0@mE3TZdSOAoRzbyttVSGLhPK0SUHK4KYQy2rkzXe0ghdDvZyNWd87JhylAOU59jGKuF@y4Hj2WOFANMhGisHTH2QQYjphYn/2oNGt0hirlOK0@iLGP44iTwkgcTo/ur8bgLlnXCOokK0at4TZdgkledTEuz8fXZMZxDiIRTFMkaEYta2NV6mJoatQvha9aIgYwHkTtiYrp8UhJKF8mawwdrxZ1jldKaDMvZMEO4AcHT2dGMjx1XrQ1sYM2piTmYs9QkKBYLpATxiho5bTC1xXSjRsZdN/hLfMJK9jvGtlZ0ZEpWtN3dj@pSmI3EnOYsPo9Pk2e1YWWUBqIqIA2WZkrkP@zHPZ0G1SLrW6u8JGExKL9Pve3DjJ/cHc7BVyR66yJklPLH8ByEzdxlOTlPya8/A6WEDHOanWQnaMlODimdD1lyuAvrtztK4uP3jIXvXw) - Java

Takes its input in unary, as an optional `-` sign followed by a string of `x` characters, the count of which represents the absolute value of the number. (As such, it is not bijective unary, as zero can be represented in two ways. The regex works with both.)

Sets a flag for whether a negative sign is present. Operating on the absolute value, repeatedly divides by 4 (requiring that there is no remainder), and then asserts that the remaining number is 1 if there was no negative sign, or 2 if there was.

```
\b                    # Anchor on the border between {start or "-"} and "x"; in the
                      # domain of this problem, it is actually equivalent to
                      # (?<=^(?=x)|-|x$) - so it can anchor on the end instead of the
                      # beginning, but that would result in a non-match.
(?=(^|x))             # \1 = 1 if negative sign is present, 0 if not
(                     # loop the following:
    (x*)\3\3(?=\3$)   # assert tail is divisible by 4; tail = tail / 4
)*                    # iterate as many times as possible (minimum 0)
x                     # tail -= 1
\1                    # tail -= \1
$                     # assert tail==0
```

### Regex (ECMAScript), 36 bytes

```
^(-(x*)(?=\2$))?((x*)\4\4(?=\4$))*x$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NbsIwEIRfhVoIdpPGhCiqKozJqQcO5dAeSyu5YBK3xrFsAyk/z54mh0q9rDTzjWY1X@Io/MYpGxJv1Va6fW2@5U/ruJGnwYssnxoLcOaLSdR@QAJNhFDwdTZELKBX63yd907eOVEzbKPJGWmoX4NTpgSkXquNhIf7JEdknqfsVCktATR3Umy1MhIQ77g5aI2XkmvqrVYBxpSOkakdgOEl1dKUocJFdr0qvxIrUNwK5@XSBCjf0nfEPyD/A7OYFtNZjzFUrj6RpTkKrbYDJ0wpZwMSa7arHTA155KpOMb@Iah5WpCEzAjBmDSEOmmlCPAsQkXFpwfV9dG9CJsKHOLFj0a2Gxug3zdl9hB8cF2I3W5tkqX5I6X9/QU)

This was the original version I posted; I'm keeping it here, as it's sufficiently different, yet close enough in length, to be interesting.

If it sees a negative sign, it strips it and divides the number by 2 (requiring that there is no remainder). It then asserts that the remaining number is a power of 4.

```
^
(
    -                 # eat a leading negative sign
    (x*)(?=\2$)       # assert tail is even; tail = tail / 2
)?                    # do the above optionally
# Assert that tail is a power of 4
(                     # loop the following:
    (x*)\4\4(?=\4$)   # assert tail is divisible by 4; tail = tail / 4
)*                    # iterate as many times as possible (minimum 0)
x$                    # assert tail == 1; if this fails to match, the regex engine will
                      # try backtracking the loops, but that cannot result in a match
```

## Regex (Perl / PCRE / Boost / Python / Ruby / .NET), 32 bytes

```
^(-)?((x*)\3\3(?=\3$))*x(?(1)x)$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LasMwEPyVJYhYm/iluL1UVuxAeu2ptyo1TolBoCau5IKKcH/dldNALsvO7OzObH8y@nH6/AFiOHh9@Wg1kIwHKMr97nW3HaG7GEqsyHm55ehBdQGh7406D7CQ5wUfodbC9loNNJKpTKPYfh/tELaaOGExw9PXrKvubB54fCIN8vmcDaatqXW5QV/rN3YQoeYHfrNWN0hUKa7j0K3X6FUHlEZJ5IKkzBFSiFwEDtqjDQwiiF/IiMnQE7tcXvNe44ZfGP@PTxQfx7Fpnl/2TTO90wQrSt0KZSELWglZEMSVoxVl6JBMU8LyzUOazvUP) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNa4NAEL3nVyyysDOJGk16KF3FS1sIlB7a3mK6GLtGwayLGhBCfrudDT11YYf5ePPezNjazklma8t4z1LmrT0WMtvrk@q1bYtSg1iHy0ypumhHVXZn27S6zyFHmX@sB@EzQb@ipDppBzCjNuMASr3u3l6UQp/FSJRELBdV1wNv0kjyNq0IPsDn1/PuHSVeWVMBb/fD2LfakIdBfEhTLzceEni4HKlCaT/ygxhdv55s2/1o8MLQ8wkviaDsLmZ0zcmGuvbEQDY6yAVjd2nzF3OTpPc6easVkjaD@87nYixr4L1P2CTKRCCehMCQtN05dDGCmIRfHAeqIz12dWM3qMu6c7NKRuvFkrmYcSNvpHz7dztAOX9DgBnAtMR8m28hS/MtR1xOkEGME/J5DjbRw2MYOvsL) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLBkppAEL37Fb3uVugWMKKpHEC0Kp@QyiEpNRTiCFORgQIs2U3tr6/pGaJBN3NgmOnu916/nqQs3TRJzo9SJYfjTsB8WxR187ESqWjHWVkuBkkWVxCVqw2E8HX45XT6tZ0dfzw/f/@WfT5leP6JLi0R2xGtZ@sZLsP17Ilo1OISPWrp6Uz3NUMHRmUYlbYXDP4RS@atRJwvBo87sZdKQB63GDtbAsSYFrhlmph83mkgVcNhqZDg9wB4lSuuPgiFJbneJpwEcOSc2TRqoNAnXZDqn7rZ@T7nSpXyZXlsAlOfFKpuwDTv@6Z7qASWzs2V78skrgUFl9s6j5skg1MW/4XZFxWg5nq5cqWiOXA3aA6JVE5HS8FFul66RE3Y4bgpJJqEcRKxTCRyQHkOlEXN4S7C7uxwOB4PKbgiKI/DOukh7Pfo@0pfLv8DDLbJt2FK4DN7cKsmZzwzgW2NasIqzI9HPU7zNEZalxKn7rRSuT3dBJCLvBYN1jZLt1qLe8jZtlqHzXiuGFfHZKj0nOah8gKwbdm35ypKSW0CLEKYMKQ@GFU5uXqXTCH3gA@cR5pM6kdruVZwi8Qp/bFGtYirJEPs@UYfdLnNQBvHzNfh90D3mi5oLwRsrDYArbWyWMZL6AXvUrsnUBwbmM9B3sZf30m866LtddEld99KNMdKAVv6ena9yfTTeKy/b8n@EKf12T2YViPT6R8) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7basMwDEDf8xXC9EHKxcTNnpKafEiTQba5rYdnB9lj6ddndcdehBDnHLTe0y34brdfa@AE8R5rNvVnDH4A1iyE2F@xoRFxK2nqpg5HPXUHonLDERVtdNgf0Fn1jZoHsLotLoHBgfU5JmP6sL4vwGkn4@psQiGloALsBZzx6Oh07MFV2hWQRZ9FXvzVoPUJ3bmdqf7b1EyVokcru2xkNAu/35BrEI0o0Z9aqsQmyuUtoqcnmEnbw8q5QM@DVsP/Y@E7yR@2yWBMnJW9Ue3xRco8fwE) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9La8MwDL7vV2imUCkjIo@dlppQ6K47jN2SNrTUTQ3GDY5Ls8v@emaXrQcJPul7SO56@J4dSPhUvZoGtuoGm/XXmp3aHyvQMqvgdtZGgZG98uMTgD6BadJ8K6VorajCwjQZc1psK1D2GBhhwuNgtMcl85L@NGyU7f0ZaVUEURMMgu6hOV0cWNAW4pD9pdOYZ8QciQ8YeHcvRLvKapGKNyHoRUwisbw/jATyB1wVGfo5Xj5c/XgPiJ/kATttPdj/zNhjdd37x6br5h2mVCNOCbVlW2It23JBlExYY04TLeY5zbPilTn2Xw) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RaoQwEEV/RWQgGW2Crn1aCW7pc79ALVg3WwNpIjGLsuK329hS@jJw5t65zB3tLN00SK13cKJ28lMu7fls5EwvZH@nDCtKlwSboiloJZoCEJOFVjTHBWEnl6f41X6NSstrjCU8RFberJNdP1DQkTIRKDPePa7QCdBsGrXyccMbHpfqRqHjvb0bz7SPTocnFdDVWbuFDApG1Mr49mdTgmFa/nF@cJriemQ4/tb5fpATJYwk9DD6KMOULCSpgzSEPi8fUxAQfy8euM5OeckGO/ktPJ2X/xwxY0N9rYyMwGzbtrM8Oz1zfsxv) - .NET

Uses essentially the same algorithm as the 33 byte ECMAScript version, but in a more straightforward way, which never matches strings outside the problem's domain.

```
^
(-)?                  # \1 = negative sign if it is present; unset otherwise
(                     # loop the following:
    (x*)\3\3(?=\3$)   # assert tail is divisible by 4; tail = tail / 4
)*                    # iterate as many times as possible (minimum 0)
x                     # tail = tail - 1
(?(1)x)               # if \1 is set, then tail = tail - 1, else do nothing
$                     # assert tail == 0
```

---

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 26 bytes

```
^((.*)\2\2(?=\2$))*(x|oo)$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NTwIxFEX/Ck4IvDdIGSbEGGqHlQsWstClaFLhMfO0dJq2fIjw20dmYeLmbs7NvTmfeq/DyrOLw@B4TX5b2y/6bryydOg8U/l4dAAnVYzS5h1ApLjMlznM1DLvIqZwPNc1dpt0dEIR65fo2ZaAIhheEdzdDieIMqhMHio2BGCUJ702bAkQb5TdGYM/pTIiOMMR@kL0UfIGwKpSGLJlrLDIz2cOC70AVk77QHMboXzN3hD/AP0HthjPxtMWY6x8fUjmdq8Nrzte25KmnWRg5Kb2IPlBkeTBANtD4CKbJcdkmtQJCk@OdIQnHSuhPwLwdUxsdVxV4BF/Qq/nrqYRWrmxdLsYor@W5OXSDPNsci9Em78) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LasMwEPyVJYhImzh@0UKJLNuB9NpTb1UqnBKDQI1dywUX1f11V3YDvQw7s4@ZbS@duZ/ev4B0HJxp3ioDJOKeiux4eD7kI9RNx4gVMc9yjg507Rm6ttPXHlbyuuIjlEbY1uieURnKkAb282x7v6WCXRIkePmY54p/NfY67olCPp@z3rTqSpOl6ErzkpyEx/jEb9b6RonOxNL21XaLTtfAmG/ncUEHuqcNRRigOluvIYL4gYh0ETpi1@sl7RLWf5Lwv/BE83EclXp8Oio1vTIWblCmMmWFkClB3LDhu2mQTNMuje8ewnDGXw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNtT9swEP7Or7hFTLVLMWm1TwQPbdMmTRrbBB/bTnITpzE4dmY7NMD47d05zQaVakWx78XP3T13vhX34vS2uNuqurEuwC3KTFk2zuC1pg1KH9Q5uZYdWo6adqVVDrkW3sOVUAaeYND5IAJu91YVUKOF3ASnzBqEW/v5kkKonN14@NzlsgnK4s0jgC9KSyi5kZv@SBKW20IytCc0@9iWpXSyuJaikA5Wvdu@kvy7OYglpdkQ109CtqkiPiGer7AGUXxTRhJK33DTak1VSTyTv1uhPUnOxuNxQunTvusOgZBwEOAJEcJ/BAQ4Q4QV@t1l/oSPFmYU95A973TPP0UI0hlwfDhhtXUTA3iaIRsra7UUBh55iYgyg5tcGIOlK9O0ATjEagcduXnwQdZMGZrBUGfvxirhv8suYJo9xQADIRpzR4ydk0GPocTBPl@CRnP0Yr7RKpBksWD4YSfwUgCTovmrCTgLjjXCeYkC0fN0SSdgpgeNTEuzDtXFDC4hesI5btMlIuaVcPNlNxTVS1ciVKwWHekPYuWJSenkRZhSuszgg3PiwbNSaU26iUnf8/Ry1I3OR3bUkwhQWhe5wIy5STMwF9xMcTs5QUKwY4bzlO6j4H1MCSPlFbJdY1IOE@kl0r8Cg4/lE@a4mz62caIhA0Rum4cf5bUwa4lI6at8KS6krgRSYyBTYEdi/Ec6tM5iHzZOBUniqNDskQfXxq6/mBvsTChJ8tYnyDHNnuM6irO6/UUIG9PFbDEjl3wxO6Z0TLo/1tLjbZzE7ek0nb1jLP7/Ag) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbjpswEH3nK6bZVbEDocBWfYCQSP2Eqg@tkhQRxwGrwVgYlOy2@@tNx6ZJSVo/@DbHZ86cMVNqVjJ2fhCSHfodh/m2aXT3ruUlPwWVUguHVUULuVptIINPk4/H4/ftU//1@fnL5@rDsSLnb4QEU7qO1zFZZuv4kdIpOf1sGvp4pvfoiQ9TleXKi1Lnb0qBGVte1AvnYcf3QnKoixMp/C0FQgq6IFu6xDXBlTpCdhgWklD44QAOtcLXBy6JorNok4Up9Ih5ivMOGnMyD0qz0d0uSRArZImXqu9S@541Undgy04SWze0nCj/5ipJBCs0p@nlVtdFxyo4VsUfmn3TAjG5Xq65St4dsBpiD0xIf0hL04t0M8wTGaK3RdcIYgEBy1EmodQHGfmgGo3hIYLu7MgkCCY0vTLICMMG9CYb15gk0lwu/0MMnsV7EFNIMHt6q6ZGPtuBrSYyRBV2E9FRTvsppkaX5MfhtJK1F21SqHmteUc0ig8XWbh0T27iNi4ea7RPI8w06cp09U1k0nRrnskoBc8TY5OstD3isiykowzIPfDeIk0RwlhqdNd0ZlZxD0K6cYdzzYuWVYSMLKRvUa7Y@LbNPn4Lei/qwvRCAf01PhB3LV0s9CWL0n@gw09o@g7mcxC38VfndjfMLe/6VgIa9nqeRWH8PgjM/IvtD0Wpz7ODrSG3JfwG) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BTsMwEEX3OcXI6mImTa04sErqcpAmSAFcajTY0diIVuLuoS5iM/r6X@9plms@x/Cw@s8lSoZ0TY245iPFMIBYUUqtz4i6prEbO3yyY7chqvHyEyNt1tt8NP3OTAN421anKMDgQ9HolN986Ctgyzot7DMqrRVV4E/ALiDTvuuBt5YrKGAooMzh3aEPGfnYTtT8JTPR1tDNVVhxOrlZXs8oDaC6qFKGQwuOkwMVFdXzS8JAd6CMvodFionuhTXD/4PxK@tv8dlhylKQdWfa7lHrcn8B) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/BasMwDL3vKzRTqB2IcMxO9bxS6K47jN2SzrTUTQ3GDo5LMxj79cwuWw968KT3nqR4OXzNERS8m95MA3pzhe3mY4PR7I8SrOISrmfrDDjVmzQ@ANgTuLZudkqRzhOZB67liLXYSTD@mBW5g@PgbKJLxCX786Azvk9nyp5FNrU5IPvunlOI4MF6KE1MQVvacIZYhHeadbcsSv0LX5OJrEggrPK4P4wM1A9EWcb2sZw9XNJ4Sy9vNJlH6xP4/4UFS2n9@rbVev6kFCvWiU7QterEgrGKTt8hsMU81w0XT4gFfwE) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNa8MwDL33V4hgiNWmaRJ2GHOzXLZBYeyw7VZ3Js2cJpDaJkmh0PW3Z3LZaQYLfTy9J8k1bloXrnHAesghWAUQg@v1QfXadWWlebiK54VSTdmNqrJH13a6l1yikO@rIYwgpF9TUh20B5hRm3HgSr1sXp@VwghSJEoiFrPa9py1eSJYl9cEH/jH59PmDQVeoK0567bD2HfakIfLdJfngTQBEng47alC6SiJlin6fn12nf3WPIjjICK8IILKnszom9cZdW2JgWyyEzOAm7T5i5lZ57c6eYsFkjbw287HcqwazvqI1PwBdEl05jEpwnP4ENowKvcDJZAeXPzELeqqsX5MAbRZKsDHwIy4kuj139k4iumL83iOMpMZL3KZMcQ5P/9Yi2yalllydx/H3v4C) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDRaoQwFER/RcKFJNoElT6tSLf0uV@gFqy9uwbSRJIsytp8u9WW0pcLM5w7MDPZGZ0fUesNXN04vOLSnU4GZ3am2xtjMuVt2ZbsqW5L4Dxly5e1HDZ6fiAv9nNSGj8Ir@Be59XFOuyHkYFOlElAmekW@Ap9DVr4SatAWtlKUqkLg14O9maC0CEpDyaroW/yLu4ZDEzdKBO6H6cCIzT@6eLQWcbXI8PJ1z4MI3pGgB2GEdeQ85UuNKL2uFJLIydps2Pj3ur53e8M57/fd77OTgUUo/Uh7gWK6l8nwth9BK0MJmBijJso8vJRyuN@Aw) - .NET

Takes its input in bijective signed unary. A nonnegative number is a string of `x` characters, and a nonpositive number is a string of `o` characters. The the length of the string is the absolute value of the number.

```
^                     # tail = N = input number
(                     # Loop the following:
    (.*)\2\2(?=\2$)   # Assert tail is divisible by 4; tail = tail / 4;
                      # use "." so that either "x" or "o" can be matched, as
                      # long as all characters are identical.
)*                    # Iterate as many times as possible (minimum 0).
(x|oo)$               # Assert tail == 1 or tail == -2
```

Answer (score 7):

**HP 28s 36 bytes**

```
WHILE DUP ABS 1 > REPEAT 2 NEG / END 1 ==
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 21 bytes

A recursive function that returns `0` or `true`.

```js
f=n=>n==1||n&&f(n/-2)
```

#### How it works

This doesn't include any explicit test -- like `n` being odd or `abs(n)` being less than one -- to stop the recursion early when the input is *not* an exact power of -2.

We exit only when `n` is exactly equal to either `1` or `0`.

This does work however because any IEEE-754 float will eventually be rounded to `0` when divided by 2 (or -2) enough times, because of [arithmetic underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>n==1||n&&f(n/-2)

console.log(f(-2));
console.log(f(-1));
console.log(f(0));
console.log(f(1));
console.log(f(2));
console.log(f(3));
console.log(f(4));
```

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 41 Bytes

```
for(;$argn%-2==0;)$argn/=-2;echo$argn==1;
```

## PHP, 52 Bytes

```
echo($l=log(abs($argn),2))==($i=$l^0)&&$argn>0^$i%2;
```

## PHP, 64 Bytes

Working with a Regex

```
echo preg_match("#^".($argn>0?1:"1+0")."(00)*$#",decbin($argn));
```

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 33 bytes

```c
f(n){return n%2?n==1:n&&f(n/-2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@mkadZXZRaUlqUp5CnamSfZ2traJWnpgYU19c10rSu/Z@bmJmnoclVzaWgUFCUmVeSpqGkmhKTp6STpqFroalpjU3cBIe4EQ5xQ@ziBtiFcajGYbgxdmEcTsThI0MzkHgt1/@vefm6yYnJGakA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:n*n&n*n-1<n%3%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk8rTw2IdQ1t8lSNVY3@FxRl5pUoROcppOUXKeQpZOYpFCXmpadq6BoaGBjogAhNhcw0hTSNPM3Y/wA)

The bit trick `k&k-1==0` checks whether `k` is a power of 2 (or `k==0`). Checking this for `k=n*n` as `n*n&n*n-1==0` tells us whether `abs(n)` is a power of 2.

To further see if `n` is a power of -2, we need only check that `n%3==1`. This works because mod 3, the value -2 is equal to 1, so its powers are 1. In contrast, their negations are 2 mod 3, and of course 0 gives 0 mod 3.

We combine the checks `n*n&n*n-1==0` and `n%3==1` into a single expression. The first can be written with `<1` for `==0`, since it's never negative. The `n%3==1` is equivalent to `n%3%2`, giving 0 or 1. So, we can combine them as `n*n&n*n-1<n%3%2`.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*Ties [emanresu A's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256288) for #1.*

```
2(вO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fSOPCJv///3WNAQ)

```
2(вO  # full program
   O  # push sum of...
  в   # list of base-10 values of base...
 (    # negative...
2     # literal....
  в   # digits of...
      # implicit input
      # implicit output
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a line to clarify only `1` is considered truthy in 05AB1E, and also added a test suite for the test cases. Feel free to change my edits if you'd want.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 34 bytes

```py
lambda n:n==(-2)**~-n.bit_length()
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 7, 55 bytes

```
boolean c(int n){return n==0?0>1:n%-2==0?c(n/-2):n==1;}
```

**Explanation:**

```
boolean c(int n){  // Method with integer parameter and boolean return-type
  return n==0 ?    //  If n is zero:
    0>1//false     //   Return false
   : n%-2==0 ?     //  Else-if n mod -2 is zero:
    c(n/-2)        //   Recursive call for the input divided by -2
   :               //  Else:
    n==1;          //   Return if n is one
}                  // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#LY5BCoMwEEX3nuJTKCSIVqUrbdoTdOWydBFTWwJxIiYWinh2G8XF8Abmz5tRRjqH@xQBzkuvFZbGWtNKgmKaPIhPQ@vHgUBCZLfsmpd0TIq1V4xOScHLMMireQH6sTHBsIu@Vr/QSU2s9oOmz@MJyddDwNsOm1xDICmqwIvAOTCO9wRQ/5xvu9SOPu3DujfENGIcShwCwnOcV1t0jtaalz8)

```
class M{
  static boolean c(int n){return n==0?0>1:n%-2==0?c(n/-2):n==1;}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    for(int i = -2; i <= 4; i++){
      System.out.println(i + ": " + c(i));
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-2: true
-1: false
0: false
1: true
2: false
3: false
4: true
```

Comment: The non-recursive way is shorter by 5 bytes: `boolean c(int n){while(0==n%-2)n/=-2;return 1==n;}`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Unfortunately that one doesn't work for `n=0` in Java, because `0%-2==0` will be `true` and `0/-2` is still `0`, causing an infinite loop, which is why I added the `n==0?0>1` part to my recursive method.

Comment: Nicely spotted!

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 21 bytes

```perl6
{$_==(-2)**(.lsb//0)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#VY1LasMwFEXnWsUjmEpKkPyJm7YxbhfSFGM7CgT8KZZTMMYF7aikX0@9FG3EscAdZHTh3fvOOUkBbxueBihv4CYt9wLCsbWiMCTMo8sl4ZlMbNuh3XgoK8iOhZCE8jx@Je2Kp2WeEBsz/LTbr2z67Lx0FFoEMMGsSshTVkMIhkqsiAZTIeMGFla0q@d6Cy02JgzvwHOZ8LqKC0mw43pr/3Zzd/@AIXwErNXH0A/n4VOrL62@tfrR6lerP616TOF4@Nd1iwB1I/MR88xfI@QWDH/oEXPNpSiRM6d7tZgMyJub9Zz@NeN8AQ)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  $_                  # is the input
  ==                  # equal to
  (-2)**( .lsb // 0 ) # -2 to the power of the least significant bit of the input
}
```

Note that [`0.lsb`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/lsb) returns [`Nil`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Nil) which produces a warning when used as a number, so the defined or operator [`//`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS) is used.
(Think of [`//`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS) as [`||`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/$VERTICAL_LINE$VERTICAL_LINE) with a different slant)

A method call with no invocant where a term is expected is implicitly called on [`$_`](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/$DOLLAR_SIGN_). ([`.lsb`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/lsb))

[Also works with](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#VY1dasJAFIXfZxUXCZ0ZJZMfrbaGaReiEmIcQTCJZGIhhBRmR8XW1rxmKbORmIH0wacD95z7fWcp4GPO4gAlJTzF2U4A7yor5JzYPh2PCUvk1nFcWnf7LIfjIRWSUJZEJ1JNWJwlW@JgG7@vdxOHrtxNTaFCAD3MyoU8HwvgYKjECmnQFzIqYWSF62Kol1BhY8LwCUbFijxKJcGu509nz/PFyysG/gZYq6@2aS/tt1Y/Wl21@tXqT6ubVg2mcNj/6@pRgOrO9s1TKeQSDLxtkO2ZS5ohd0jvYdHjkT800yFnj4zLHQ) [`.msb`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/msb).

Comment: I like this one!

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <strike>24</strike> 23 bytes

```
f 0=0
f 1=1
f n=f(-n/2)
```

Defines a function `f` which returns `1` for powers of -2 and `0` otherwise.

A golfed version of my first submission to the [other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115641/67875).

Answer (score 4):

## R, 22 bytes

Takes input from stdin, returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` accordingly.

```
scan()%in%(-2)^(0:1e4)
```

I'm not 100% sure that this is a valid answer, as it only works for integers up to R's size limit, and if the integers were unbounded it wouldn't work. However, the rules state:

> The usual integer overflow rules apply: your solution must be able to work for arbitrarily large integers in a hypothetical (or perhaps real) version of your language in which all integers are unbounded by default, but if your program fails in practice due to the implementation not supporting integers that large, that doesn't invalidate the solution.

In a hypothetical version of R which *does* allow unbounded integers, then we could use the following code, for the same byte count:

```
scan()%in%(-2)^(0:Inf)
```

Of course, in real R, the above code just gives `Error in 0:Inf : result would be too long a vector`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

```julia
!n=n∈(-2).^(0:n^2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#@6@YZ5v3qKNDQ9dIUy9Ow8AqL85I839afpFCnkJmnoKuqaGRFRBzcWamKSjmcXFyOhQUZeaVpGkoqZqkxOQp6SjkaXJxpualcAHxfwA)

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f9fMc8271FHh16chq6RjoFVXpyR5v@0/CKFPIXMPAVdU0MjKyDm4sxMU1DM4@LkLCjKzCvJydPI0@TiTM1L4QLi/wA "Julia 0.5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
!tsjQ_2
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21tsjQ_2&input=-7&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-2%0A-1%0A0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
     _2   # -2
   jQ     # Cast input to that base
          # Iff input is a power of -2, then jQ_2 returns something of the form [1]+[0]*n
          # where n is the power of -2
          # This is also the only situation in which the sum of that is 1
!ts       # so we check for that: is the (s)um equal to 1 (or, equivalently, "!(sum - 1)" )
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 14 bytes

```
__-+_-2{[?+_0:__0+_0+__?+_0
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyJfXy0rXy0ye1s_K18wOl9fMCtfMCtfXz8rXzAiLCJbLTRdIiwwXQ)

**Explanation:**

- `__-+_-`: `-2`, written as `-1 + -1` with padding
- `2`: Power
- `{[?+_0`: `log_2(abs(input))`, with `+_0` as padding
- `:`: Equals
- `__0+_0+__?+_0`: Input (`?`), with padding

So basically, `-2 ** log_2(abs(input)) == input`

Comment: Do you think you could add and explanation for this, please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## x86-32 machine code, <s>20 18</s> 16 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @xiver77
-2 bytes by removing an unnecessary jump

(This submission was originally 19 bytes, but I adjusted it to 20 since I forgot to add `ret`).

```
00000000: f8a9 ffff 7f00 7507 c1f8 1730 e0d1 f8c3  ......u....0....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJbbsIwEPz3KbauKjkSqSBBKqKAeoZeIDKOA64cG8UGQiuu3nTjkEBf@@FoZ2dfsxG7XbwRorlXRuh9LmGhrPOV5OWKXLG18k76W0RoVSL4DXI@VwZZZG2tBuWM3OzsMWGFttxDHcEHAbQ9ktIk83B6JgHIMu7KLMPvwWrulZbosFfKQrS10h5A8noED5Omx4QWQ9xL5zvCuH4qWhtCb@YdpMnJADheddQkHbDaVsD1CPj2StsGWvAxfx76RjT4c6DLFyEEBXaKeqRCrx48TKXRZb9K@n1lgLWyRLj0mZCDVXmY@qc4QboTLG/kq/s6qO98Luzew2IBdftQiFdAL2FVDOP8YtOTdMgLy2gn/yEZS/9qFRzUQIfR8XpQcmVYP3K3Ae@qH7d4PmB3XQFlHqUtWNRTr6WVgdWqT@pPyHjUAedb3cbYtolnJJ6SOCHxhIzJhCQkJVMy@xSF5hvXxGWa4IP/0RLnk/oL)

Expects a single precision float in `eax`. Output is in the carry flag.

It takes advantage of some fundamental properties of floats, for some power of -2 `n`:

- `abs(n)` is a power of 2, therefore `n`'s mantissa must be 0.
- `n` is positive for odd numbered exponents, and negative for even exponents. In other words, `sign ^ exponent[0] = 1` where `exponent[0]` is the least significant bit of the exponent.

NASM source:

```
[BITS 32]

isnegpow2:
    ; Clear carry
    clc
    ; Check if mantissa is non-zero
    test eax, 0x7fffff
    ; If it is, then abs(eax) is not a
    ; power of 2, so eax cannot be a power
    ; of -2
    jnz .end

    ; Shift away the mantissa
    sar eax, 23
    ; Now ah contains the sign,
    ; and al contains the exponent.
    ; For powers of -2, sign ^ exponent[0] = 1
    xor al, ah
    ; Check lsb by shifting it to the carry flag
    ; If it's 1, then eax is a power of -2, so the
    ; carry will be set
    sar eax, 1
.end:
    ret
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered _floating-point_ input!

Comment: Nice observation! Clever, really.

Comment: [How about this?](https://tio.run/##dVLtbsIwDPyfp/AyTUolOkFBGuoA7Rn2AlUIKWRKE9QEaDfx6uvclBb25R9pfb5e7HPFfh9vhWjulRH6sJGwUNb5UvJiRa7YWnkn/S0itCoQ/AY5v1EGWWRtrQbljNzu7SlhubbcQxXBBwGMA5KmSeahfiYByDLuiizD59Fq7pWWmLBXykK1jcIeQfJqBA@Tpse8dL4Dx9VT3sZAfzPvkHOlyYA4XnbcZDpglS2B6xHw3ZW2C7SrkABpNiFt9dKhILQI71hNQ0cRDXkKdPkihKDA6qhHSsyqIUN9Gl0mL6U/lAZYa1iEdpwJOVq1CbP9tC2YWsPyxtiq10Hn01TYg4fFAqr2oBCvgF7KKh/a@cWmtXTIC8NoJ/8hGUv/uiok6IEOreNeoeDKsL7lbgLeqZ92uFhgd52AMo/S5izqqVdpZWC16j/qF8141AHnW9/GeG0Tz0k8I3FC4gkZkwlJyJTMyPxT5JpvXRMX0wQP/MOW2J/UXw) It fits in 17 bytes. BTW, is it acceptable not to have a `ret`?

Comment: It should have a ret, you're right. I'll update the post with your improvement tomorrow when I have time to figure out how it works.

Comment: Thanks @xiver77, didn't think to set the carry flag using `sar`. Neat stuff. Managed to rearrange it slightly to golf off another 2 bytes also.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript(ES7), 45 bytes

```
x=>-1**Math.log2(Math.abs(x))*Math.abs(x)==x
```

Comment: Math.abs(x) is longer than x>0?x:-x, 11 bytes to 8 bytes. You should also be able to do -2**... instead of -1... to remove the second Math.abs(x)

Comment: What's ES7 specific in this?

Comment: @DobbyTheFree-Elf, `**` is.

Comment: What interpreter are you using. This code is syntax error on my Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/jan/src/plweb/index.html), 44 bytes

```
p(X):-X=1;X\=0,X mod 2=:=0,Z is X/(-2),p(Z).
```

[Online interpreter](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/naQGHdxk.pl)

Answer (score 3):

## bc 88 bytes

```
bc -l <<< "n=$1;q=l(sqrt(n*n));p=4*a(1);((n<1)*c(q/l(2)*p/2)+(n>1)*(s(q/l(4)*p)))^2==0"
```

I have this in a file `neg2.sh` and it prints `1` for powers of `-2` and `0` otherwise

I know it's really long, but it was fun

#### Test

```
$ for i in {-129..257}; do echo -n "$i: "; ./neg2.sh $i; done | grep ': 1'
-128: 1
-32: 1
-8: 1
-2: 1
1: 1
4: 1
16: 1
64: 1
256: 1
```

#### Explanation

The main body has two halves, both are trying to equal zero for powers of `-2`.

```
q=l(sqrt(n*n))               % ln of the absolute value of the input
p=4*a(1)                     % pi: arctan(1) == pi/4
q/l(2) -> l(sqrt(n*n))/l(2)  % change of base formula -- this gives
                             % the power to which 2 is raised to equal
                             % sqrt(n*n). It will be an integer for 
                             % numbers of interest
n<1                          % 1 if true, 0 if false. for negative
                             % numbers check for powers of 2
n>1                          % for positive numbers, check for powers
                             % of 4
c(q/l(2)*p/2)                % cos(n*pi/2) == 0 for integer n (2^n)
s(q/l(4)*p)                  % sin(n*pi) == 0 for integer n (4^n)
(....)^2==0                  % square the result because numbers are
                             % not exactly zero and compare to 0
```

Comment: I never expected trigonometry!  Good answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Casio BASIC](http://community.casiocalc.org/topic/2448-casio-basic-tutorial/), 76 bytes

Note that 76 bytes is what it says on my calculator.

```
?→X
0→O
While Abs(X)≥1
X÷-2→X
If X=1
Then 1→O
IfEnd
WhileEnd
O
```

This is my first venture into Casio BASIC... I never realised I could write such decent programs on a calculator :D

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 10 bytes

-3 thanks to @rak1507

```apl
⊢∊¯2*⍳∘|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KOuRY86ug6tN9J61Lv5UceMGpA8UDxNwZALxjKGs0zgLKCO/wA)

Comment: Currently fails for 1, can be fixed with ⎕IO←0 and can be golfed to `⊢∊¯2*⍳∘|`

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 14 bytes

```
{|/x=*\1,x#-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqrpGv8JWK8ZQp0JZ16j2f5q6rpGCrqGCgYKhgpGCsYLJfwA)

- `*\1,x#-2` return list of -2 raised from 0 to `x`, i.e. (`1 -2 4 -8`)
- `|/x=` are any items in that list equal to `x`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 6 bytes

```
ȧʀudec
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%C8%A7%CA%80udec&inputs=-2&header=&footer=)

Very rude, I know, but it gets the job done.

### Explained

```
ȧʀudec
ȧʀ     # range(0, abs(input) + 1)
  ud   # -2 (-1 * 2). 2N would have worked just the same, but that wouldn't be as funny now would it.
    e  # -2 ** the range (vectorises)
     c # is input in ^
```

Comment: `r` is for rude

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
1|¬0&~×₂ṅ↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/37Dm0BoDtbrD0x81NT3c2fqobcP///EWAA)

#### Explanation

A recursive solution:

```
1|          Either the input is 1 (base case), or...
  ¬0        The input is not 0
    &       and
     ~×₂    some integer times 2 equals the input
        ṅ   Negate that integer
         ↰  and call the predicate recursively
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
ḃb-₂ᵐ×?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO5iTdR01ND7dOODzd/v//eAsA) Or, [verify all inputs from -8 to +16](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bG04v@P9zRnKT7qKnp4dYJh6fb//8fHW@hoxBvDsRmQGwKxCZAbAzERkBsqKNgoKMAJIEcoBhQCqgCqBCoHqjNEigFkgbKGwIVGAJVGAKVGALVGJrF/o8AAA).

#### Explanation

```
ḃ        Convert to binary, ignoring the sign (so -2 and 2 both become [1,0])
 b       Behead: remove the first element
  -₂ᵐ    Subtract 2 from each element
     ×   Product of that list
      ?  Assert that the result equals the original input number
```

Some examples to show how this works:

```
         -8          1    2      0    6
ḃ        [1,0,0,0]   [1]  [1,0]  [0]  [1,1,0]
 b       [0,0,0]     []   [0]    []   [1,0]
  -₂ᵐ    [-2,-2,-2]  []   [-2]   []   [-1,-2]
     ×   -8          1    -2     1    2
```

- If the number is \$(-2)^n\$ for some integer \$n\$, `ḃb` produces a list of \$n\$ zeros; subtracting 2 from each turns it into a list of \$n\$ copies of \$-2\$, and taking the product gives us \$(-2)^n\$ again.
- If the number is \$-(-2)^n\$, we get \$(-2)^n\$ instead, which doesn't match the input.
- For any other number, `ḃb` gives a list containing some amount of \$-2\$ mixed with \$-1\$. The product of this list is \$\pm2^m\$ for some \$m\$; but since our input is not of the form \$\pm2^m\$, it doesn't match.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 14 bytes

```
max(Ans=(-2)^randIntNoRep(0,abs(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`. `randIntNoRep(0,` can be replaced with `cumSum(1 or rand(` for greater compatibility and +4 bytes. `-` represents the negative sign.

Faster but larger answer that works for larger numbers:

#### <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
Ans=(-2)^int(log(abs(Ans)+not(Ans),2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 27 bytes

```
+`(1+)\1
$1_
^(1|-1_)(__)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@doGGorRljyKViGM8Vp2FYo2sYr6kRH6@ppfL/v64hFAAA)

Takes input in unary, which is fairly standard for Retina. The first two lines do partial unary to binary conversion based on the first two lines of code from the [Tutorial entry](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/Tutorial:-Unary-arithmetic#unary-to-binary) (any extraneous `1`s will cause the match to fail anyway), while the last line checks for a power of four or a negative odd power of two.

```
+`(1+)\1\1\1
$1_
^(-1)?1_*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@doGGorRljCIJcKobxXHEauoaa9obxWir//@saQgEA)

This time I do partial unary to base four conversion. Powers of four end up as `^1_*$` while negative odd powers of two end up as `^-11_*$`.

```
+`\b(1111)*$
$#1$*
^(-1)?1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@dEJOkYQgEmloqXCrKhipaXHEauoaa9oYq///rGkIBAA)

This time I just keep dividing by four as much as I can and check for `1` or `-11` at the end.

```
+`\b(1+)\1\1\1$
$1
^(-1)?1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@dEJOkYaitGWMIgipcKoZccRq6hpr2hir//@saQgEA)

Another way of dividing by four. And still annoyingly 27 bytes...

Answer (score 2):

## [Fourier](https://github.com/beta-decay/Fourier), 53 bytes

```
I~X1~N~G0(0-2*G~GX*X~PG*G>P{1}{0~O~N}G{X}{1~O0~N}N)Oo
```

I'll work on golfing this later, but the outline of this is:

```
X = User input
G = N = 1
Loop until N = 0
    G = -2 * G
    P = X*X 
    If G*G > P then
        N = O = 0
    End if
    If G = X then
        O = 1
        N = 0
    End if
End loop
Print O
```

Where the output is `0` for *falsey* and `1` for *truthy*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fourier#@@9ZF2FY51fnbqBhoGuk5V7nHqEVURfgruVuF1BtWFttUOdf51frXh1RW21Y528AZPtp@uf//69raAYA)

Comment: In the algo description not would be better not use P variable and write 
    If G\*G > X\*X then...?

Comment: @RosLuP That would be better, but Fourier would simply treat that as `(G*G > X)*X`

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, <s>51</s> 50 chars

Not very short, but I hope interesting :)

```
x=>eval(`for(w=q=1;w<=(x<0?-x:x);w*=2,q*=-2)q==x`)
```

Test:

```js
f=x=>eval(`for(w=q=1;w<=(x<0?-x:x);w*=2,q*=-2)q==x`)
for(x=-2049; x<2049; ++x) if(f(x)) console.log(x)
```

Comment: `w<=(x<0?-x:x)`=>`w<=x|w<=-x`

Answer (score 2):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 12 bytes, non-competing

```
/o|\ntzR2
@i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@fXxOTV1IVZMTlkPn/v64FAA)

#### Explanation

Alice has a fairly weird built-in, which was added because I needed something that goes well thematically with the string operation "discard everything up to this substring". That operation is "drop small factors" and what it does for positive **x** and **y** is that it divides **x** by all of its prime factors less than or equal to **y**. But if **y** is negative, then Alice tries negative prime factors greater than or equal to **y** instead, which means that every time a prime factor is removed, the sign of **x** changes. So if we use **-2** as the second argument, we'll end up with **1** if and only if the input is a power of **-2** (if the input is not a power of two, other factors will remain in the end, and if it has the wrong sign, we'll end up with **-1** instead of **1**).

The rest of the program is just a bit of weird control flow.

```
/   Reflect southeast. Switch to Ordinal.
i   Read all input as a string.
    Reflect off boundary, move northeast.
|   Reflect northwest.
    Reflect off boundary, move southwest.
i   Read all input as a string, but there's no input left, so this pushes "".
    Reflect off boundary, move northwest.
/   Reflect west. Switch to Cardinal.
    Wrap around to the end of line 1.
2R  Push -2. (Really: push 2, negate.)
z   Drop small factors. When trying to find a second integer argument,
    this discards the empty string and then implicitly converts the input
    string to an integer. Turns only valid inputs to 1.
tn  Decrement, logical NOT. Effectively an "equals 1?" check.
\   Reflect southwest. Switch to Ordinal.
    Reflect off boundary, move northwest.
o   Implicitly convert result to a string and print it. 
    Reflect off boundary, move southwest.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 57 bytes

```clj
(defn i[n](if(= n 1)true(if(=(int n)0)false(i(/ n -2)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clojure#HYlBCoAgEEWv8pczC8laBp1EXAhpCTKFGR3fpj68xX@v0xqTIDvxlBMtEIzc6h3/R1kahC2nUC5VNGg3E3/rdFbNRUDpqHABVINsEWa0FgpjfvaoOSOwV7i/)

Full function, with annotations:

```clj
;; Define function `is-pow?` with 1 argument, `n`
(defn is-pow? [n]
  ;; If n = 1, that means it's a power of -2,
  ;; so we return true
  (if (= n 1) true
    ;; When we recursively call the function,
    ;; -1 > n > 1. `int` rounds up when the number
    ;; is negative (`(int -1/2)` = 0), and rounds down
    ;; when the number is positive. It also catches
    ;; the edgecase of 0.
    (if (= (int n) 0) false
      ;; If n made it to here, n < -1 or n > 1 - we have
      ;; to call the function recursively.
      (is-pow? (/ n -2)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 51 bytes

```
(defun f(n)(or(= 1 n)(and(< 1(abs n))(f(/ n -2)))))
```

Recursive version. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##FYwxCsMwFEOvIgIFeQglnULb9CKlg1PngyHxD7Y7dPHVHUeTnuDpu/q010q3yC9AGAw1csKA1mxwfGKgnVNDQ@EVAf3NnKlcVXeIRnhI1A39iKwY4RRs82YzMrpiMb1Q7u@g5fFfUvmUS9cUCvx5cwA)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwFESvMriaLKS1iCDYw6TGTwP6v8SU7nr1NDqbeW8WM6/x2EthWOSjEKqjJT7RoZLXwAkd/euo6ii8QdE@3JnC1WyHWEKEJNvQ9vdxQDZc/X0vCgqiQ7AKljafkdH8Apq6nhd/ "Common Lisp – Try It Online")

Comment: @Deadcode , added, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 28 bytes

```
=(-2)^INT(LOG(ABS(B2),2))=B2
```

Or using approach from @[Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)'s Mathematica approach:

**29 bytes**

```
=ISEVEN(LOG(MAX(B1,-2*B1),2))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 32 bytes

```perl
$.*=-2while(abs)>abs$.;$_=$.==$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FT8tW16g8IzMnVSMxqVjTDkio6FmrxNuq6NnaqsT//69ramj0L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```rust
|x|(|mut e|{while e*e<x*x{e*=-2}e==x})(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BDsIgFAX3nuLZFb@RxFJXKt5Fk08kodS0NJIAZ0fdy3bmZd6yraEaj@luvSCkHeA4wJxhvLCjIsgbHvPsoGuOWeRpC@Cc3k/rGNzzNfYxca@lKqx1LCQGqpdv5rVYH5zfiy6V7gAjpCL6L4aGODZ4a986GBv89OOlfgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:len(x:=bin(n))&1==x.count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCoAgEADQq8yqZqACCSoCT1It7GMN1ChiUKe33ur5Nx5O6s6HZPWYTnPNqwHpz03w6fXMgkKUKa2fanG3RMxVTskH/jswWBeAgQWCkX3DUjWFagnYgkWmidIH)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 102 bytes

```powershell
$a=$n-replace'-';$p=[convert]::ToString($a,2).length-1;if([math]::pow(-2,$p)-eq$n){return !0}return !1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxCsIwEADQX1E4aQJNsMGpJV@hWxEJ5WwK8ZKe0Q613x5d3N7wUlyQnx5DKMpoffocViALtwLOAinGFNyAlao6SLYfIr2R87VtL/GceaJRgKuN1AFpzF413XQX/cNl/yspLkKZGpJUOAPJlTG/mHb74/ZXU7byBQ)

Ungolfed:

```powershell
-2..4 | %{                                  # for loop from -2 to 4
    $n=$_                                   # setting n to current number in loop
    $a = $n-replace'-'                      # getting absolute value of num
    $p=[convert]::ToString($a,2).length-1   # converting to binary and counting 0s (2^p)

    if([math]::pow(-2,$p) -eq $n){          # seeing if -2^p is equal to the original num
        return !0                           # returns not 0 or True
    }

    return !1                               # returns not 1 or False
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, 40 bytes

```
a=input()
while a%-2==0:a/=-2
print a==1
```

Credits to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for the original [code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115525/67816) of length 43 bytes.
Had to post as a separate answer since I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: It's kind of the same thing, since I've made my answer version-universal, so it works in both Python 2 and 3. If you were to do this in Python 3, you should have added `int(input())` which would have gone over the limit of the `def`-like function. Additionally, In python 3, you must use `print()` which would of wasted 1 byte. That's why I chose that way, because in Python 3 it gets longer...

Answer (score 1):

## Cjam, 12 bytes

```
li_z2mLi-2#=
```

Explanation comes later.

Comment: I think you'll have to use `2b,` instead of `2mL`, because CJam does have arbitrary-precision integers, so your answer should work for arbitrarily large inputs (but `mL` won't be able to handle inputs correctly that can't be represented exactly as a 64-bit float). That should save bytes anyway, because you need neither the `z`, nor the `i` (although you will need to decrement the result before doing the exponentiation).

Answer (score 1):

## Scheme, 60 bytes

```lisp
(define(f n)(cond((= 1 n)#t)((<(abs n)1)#f)(#t(f(/ n -2)))))
```

Recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Axiom, 50 bytes**

```
g(n:INT):INT==(n=0 or n=1=>n;n rem 2=0=>g(n/-2);0)
```

It would return 0 if n is not power of (-2), else return 1; exercises

```
(70) -> n:=-10000;repeat(if g(n)=1 then output n; n>10000=>break;n:=n+1)
   - 8192
   - 2048
   - 512
   - 128
   - 32
   - 8
   - 2
   1
   4
   16
   64
   256
   1024
   4096
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
AḶ-2*i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/x4Y5tukZamf///zcAAA)

Explanation:

```
        Argument: -8
A       Get the absolute value of n             8
 Ḷ      Create a range from 0 to that number-1  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
  -2*   converts that range into the list       -2^0, -2^1, ..., -2^7
     i  Returns >0 if n is in this range, 0 otherwise.
```

Dennis pointed out a flaw in my approach, which I fixed by taking the absolute value of the input for the range generation.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>104</s> 107 bytes

+3 bytes, for using system, and finding another method to count bits

```cs
using System;b=>Enumerable.Range(0,1+(int)Math.Log(int.MaxValue,2)).Select(x=>Math.Pow(-2,x)).Any(x=>b==x);
```

It uses Linq to calculate all of -2-s integer powers, and then to test if the input is one them. It would be a bit shorter, if it didn't have to work in a theoretical version, where int can be of any size. Ungolfed:

```cs
bool IsPowerOfMinus2(int number)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 2 + (int)Math.Log(int.MaxValue, 2))
        // We generate an IEnumerable, with values from 0 to the length of 
        // maximum number in binary. We need to add one, because we need to
        // know, how many integers to 
        .Select(x => Math.Pow(-2, x))
        //Replace every number with -2 raised to the number
        .Any(x => number == x);    
        //Determine, if the input is one of them
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 53 bytes (filename).

Been a while since my last post of Pxem.

Backslash followed by three digits of octet: a character whose codepoint is so:

```
._.c\001.y\001.r.-\002.!XX.a.c\003.x.c\004.%.w.d.a\004.$.c\003.a\001.z.d.aY.o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVdrV@JIE/7ur2gykXQDuTSiIjE6DLjKjqKi4@sl6AkQFIwJS4Kigf3r81Z3Eklm54znSPqpqq573579p59fUFkrU6RtIVpV0M72xqZFt7a2ymtf0Lcfl@io3kT1NjrodE476PKofokUEf3vtPP9ArXajdNO56BxeXyjo79a1wdNdHTQOVhzPUxwDtn9Jw@JIZX9p2XZcwZ7@TLRGcsbILnuIvk1mNFFMEVyw0fmnSbvdJF0Z7qFrrR4nNoTpBDdtwMk2zN99mL5z0jTymXdnk@8aYCOGw/142OjoePgfWKjRzvoe@4wn@eo7728WO6A7KkD@1V1Z46Dynt5ms/Hk8/ql0eGIOJYDsmTRAFnETFkn2JtGQ3kpZCY/dFuXT9cXDaNsqZtJMSz04vW9fHNQ5wOg@p3SBDDb/WLo4erg85F67RdAx2om8/zgDw08fzRPELFb5H07X@F7ZeZYwU28p@4qDcJYPjmTQf@xBkF@bzljCwfyY9IgjQXBfGrsJQMiX2lfL794/i4cdI0alw9ZqYGuv80GgY8qwPE5GJCVKovREAGosyy6@n2q@UgIYeGluPbwmIBJK6Iy84Xvj1Akq/O1XdV9@HnQ5X49A/UZbII@Hofis3FpaE3xY7Vsx1DAKM6CcFL7C0w16LeV7ZENazVdbGnt3XVdDk@A733imK6qqr36voyggqlZVGdqHoQ46qWgZRSUfVWeHsnAykFcTfFrmYg1TZFdZRib2TgDnAfUhB091dwazsDKQVpP@XoRgZSCqZfU@ytDKQahDlMeaJlINUgTDtleycDKa2I6jSlvJyBlIL4W4q9nYG0DMbmKXY1A2kZbL@n2DsZSMtg7COVJS0LwZaVcnwzAymFNAQp3ZUMpBrYekllZTsDqQa2Binl1QysQAWKKQim5RXcAG4uBcERMQXB0jqDSylaLgMSrQGV71xqeMi6d64PoFEP2RwTKyYxsemyX6VgElE1N8yySVWQ8lWlAG09T3a6SFXN0cVcqN69zd8/rEFXzYVtveeAwqX@DqtCRaqu3t3HXNZMoooGakaH7CIpNn93/7XUBbvgAb6LhuBC@StiLjzFMhEdKQVgcc8i6xDPhLspqiVG7YELUKYQUC70YVRXJ3rvHKiRWOkrKPgUHHwKDtRmIpgRSzhxHmpTXQwjc18RUw17AZdG9YQS1HlqxVwbOKZ7h@SPbmHAtAXTFAVC4vnpRsGqnGWB2IRXMgrOimYtwdva@adKhfsWnGdrkuTjCDLTrENe5nFxeWZXeYvycxhr4v@RK5EncdV/N1FK9tJUPdTRMN4vDcGkAgl5IPhu4rmjh77/OrSnwUsxJ67LXSZtUkx09TGSYe1ohrRkLhnrDJs05llpj/xZDwusHkKJzd6HsVCDzbnEzZJlbDAr/yfhpqj2prb1zAGUrY4Fx/MmyPUC9GIF/aeR@yiA6Ge4oL3I3MdE7YGTmBLC3cxxghYBEcA/CVjngAKQyFIgaz//atdPDgxJeVD6pqZR5Z3/ThUZvmUld32tWJyzocz5t6KsrytvykCxOBBjpsWnfTD6jeJJa43T9uVB@9JYW@tbvg2HHrcjoJGLcEEtLAqmqW1uF0h0xZFUxuAiEtxxdN32rf7aZDpyg@Hn3MVbH8l9BPyfQ2M4c/vByHNNpPvTviF9OzhstUN/ClcROBHtAVnC8TgUpDPcJOHF3XPpOyZdo6nDsFssxswDTMKpHcymLsoVQSAm/70iA3GPxuTvKzLTElMvM1RmRqYJ7xp3SNgxQITblWU9luzEAjPcIGEUpmDC37onlBox7xB3SrefuuFu5Yxce0/bF7WanLh0FBkQqc576543bhFaTBBIhoQi0i/mfzDzM9dITNbxSewOOlkIfSuAXLNr2yhAicUJhPv2NHJsnIPsEe8zaTAKgbJYzPA1MGKqi1ulq1Kz5JAQliOfEl4ZIKA7hmO7j8ETviI6u9rorV1HJzOMmwY47gdTfFUqFlslaOl/BR6EsN8sVqq1yiZZxtpHYPMMH67MPeCTUqN0W7oh4YkhKA811IalY6GB3R@9wF0MIrMf7Sl8J7NA0BsGzNVv4bLJPdC5k5Xt3UY@39jdrBK@GHWgNf4V7it3G5tdEfaRW6NSkRvx5Gi9ggiuRtNoBXLQMIyNMgkjEbgTByN3Zi9ZeploY7dSBZm9zW3CSJHxldlIM7kx8A1BDblS1Vmd9DN8W7hJAu0n2T7Dl6vw/YR6/VmWVyjAuHRFwpahcUNjg7copHvMmrI0luWuccWqwlCry4mtYrHL8bib5Hq6sghZxHyhkQIrdWLqbbUSfnFijs9L3EQOlhbLZw7QOW@DK@N8lwnGE6/iGe9/nLH3mxkfn9bZFG5dXnkQJN4/wTo0VvQXoD@zvQeeB2eYMRNOD1uQuKhv/2Zte4atfZhYtFjQtes4eH216AsGlcsFbO1qpMCqAt8kef/8qmwcr4HrODo8LjgEugFsCMo6HAwKdJpQQ7f2FK5Jo9eRD3udwJqAJd/aH@85@@N1p@asj2t8rMJYHUMtltFOCG4ZWhdqzl4Jv26kfSJIsWdDHD0kPkXijVtYePyQMaKjJjre4fYERw97rslT95ku@jMYDSQkIXlYTs4kuI2c4Txhb5nEiM2bMDroQmg43ojPxaJeLI53MdsaWbNBCqN0jmMIA6L/3jkWwcB2bHjZQdGghbnKlgGNDZvGLkwv0qiV@Ybf4hqLFPo72oqLEYaNWvcW1tszvKQROzbYi/aOnTL81TtjXe69sNccEKf/Ia5e4YMKktuVjMBigSfwsqzDS3U0KNnB6MUuTfqTWenV/9AH8CYli9QrvvLHV/wisEYOXEwrqSyzy3FYZTcUfg2SFhg0mKaLitHlWi7TynalurFVqZJFDxIG@YOjUkjChe3XEDFGIk7e7fXO4cNJ/Xqx4PMr2s4WUcsyLSNCkBTv1j2jh0SN7AGMT4qe3jMEYXnQbiaEpYQWc2v6CNG35igu3vynXP4/)
Through this problem I noticed a bug in my interpreter.
Maybe I need to redesign the interpreter; shortening the code makes maintainance difficult.

### Usage

- As a string of decimal integer from stdin for input.
- Outputs a letter Y for truthy; nothing for falsey.

### How it works: with comments

```
XX.z
# push an integer of input
.a._XX.z
# NOTE Pxem does not have negative constants
# So negative inputs must be changed to positive
# and then get multiplied by two
.a.c\001.y\001.r.-\002.!XX.aXX.z
# Pxem does not have log() nor something similar
# Just keep dividing by four
# And exit if it seemed not to be 4^n
.a.c\003.xXX.z
  .a.c\004.%.w.d.aXX.z
  .a\004.$XX.z
.a.c\003.aXX.z
# final check for <4
.a\001.z.d.aY.o
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86_(32/64) machine code, 23 bytes

```
\x0f\xbc\xc1\xf3\x0f\xb8\xc9\xa8\x01\x74\x06\x01\xc8\x3c\x20\xf5\xc3\x83\xf9\x01\x74\xf9\xc3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/tToQwEPwNT7GpkrQ5uIDoeV9cfA9rCJTiNeGKKb0Lau7ZcReN@qPdme3s7FQlr0pNN8aq7txo2A@@Mf3yeJjKsvLemfrsdVlyPmjlTW85W3o9eiaEAHWsHNTGPr9AETI5pq0cayVHlcmxzX/4GvlGjhXWFPuP91hX31hhL0f9XYr6B@Q4s8bTbv60hFXOdtPgK28UGOuh5XRbAZ9hQMjtwgDTDqeyhEvfoa7TwMMgYKf@ArdZDFGkq1Fa6Rl1VdV1lJttiRVPSikG3ImY6IKwFdv5DadwQqC/0/7sLK26hiEtPVXG8jnCm0PechY1UL97PUjLYhjMh@5bjlsEJJCRRds7mJMbKCDJVjsE@wIILBZmtvrvlRwgamYvE9OXBXlcf5OklGSavgA)

This is a kind of problem for which the CPU usually has a built-in instruction to solve it easily but most high level languages don't support it straightforwardly.

Two x86 instructions does the main job.

- `bsf` - count trailing zeros (bit-scan forward)
- `popcnt` - count bits set

The `bsf` type of instruction is very common on many architectures with varying names. `popcnt` is a less popular one, but ARM and RISC-V also supports it as an extension.

#### algorithm

When you look at the binary representation of an integer power of -2, you can see a pattern.

```
16 -> 10000
4 -> 100
1 -> 1
-2 -> ..110
-8 -> ..11000
-32 -> ..1100000
```

When the trailing-zero count is even, there is one bit set. When the trailing-zero count is odd, the sum of this and the set-bit count equals the word size.

#### assembly

```
; out: carry flag, in: eax = 1, ecx = arg
entry:
    bsf eax, ecx
    ; if ecx == 0 then eax == 1
    ; relies on an undocumented behaviour (for Intel)
    popcnt ecx, ecx
    test al, 1
    jz even
    add eax, ecx
    cmp al, 32
flip:
    cmc
    ret
even:
    cmp ecx, 1
    je flip
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>21</s></sup> 17 bytes

```
+/@(=_2:^i.@>:@|)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tfUdNGzjjaziMvUc7KwcajT/a3JxpSZn5CukKegawVnG/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
2Nτ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIyTs+E4oiRIiwiIiwiLTgiXQ==)

Port of [Makonede's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216718/100664), outputting 1 for truthy and anything else for falsy.

```
   ∑ # Is exactly one of
  τ  # Digits in base...
2N   # -2
     # Truthy?
```

Comment: The challenge asks specifically for a truthy/falsey result, though (or implicitly with the `[decision-problem]` tag). Unlike 05AB1E, I don't think only `1` is truthy in Vyxal, or is it as well? EDIT: [doesn't seem like it](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCqGnDl+C2niIsIiIsIi04Il0=), `-8` is considered truthy.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, but it seems unfair that an output method is considered valid in one language and not in another...

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 9 bytes

```
ĐÅř⁻2~⇹^∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yITDrUdnPmrcbVT3qH1n3KOOjv//dQ0B)

```
Đ            implicit input; Đuplicate
 Å           Åbsolute value
  ř          řangify [1,2,...,n]
   ⁻         decrement
    2~       push 2; negate
      ⇹^     swap top two items; element-wise exponentiation
        ∈    is the input in the resultant list?; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
DZAR2n@sAq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharXKIcg4zyHIodCyECUPEFC00gDAA)

Port of Emigna's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
DZAR2n@sAq  # Implicit input
DZA         # Duplicate and push abs(input)
   R        # Push range(0, abs(input))
    2n@     # Push 2 ** each of the above
       sAq  # Is the input in this list?
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 55 bytes

```go
func f(n int)bool{for;n%2==0&&n!=0;n/=-2{}
return n==1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Tc7RDYIwEAbg905xkkiogFJi1IjdwRWQUNIUrqQpT4QN3MAXYuIQjuI2FuTBp7tc7vvvHs9Kj-82L1ReldDkEolsWm3s1hON9V6dFfHpcxQdFiACBImW3rSue6FNhuuU88T3ccWTDHc8TvuBmNJ2BgE5Z8PC7zOfwgMKPSHOgowUnDmwiGUg4eK6JJuGXIYsUps4dYtX487VGKjI3VaUkmGxk4wP-0XOTRg6MEeKQFIiBai_BBc8aeeXn8bxV78)

Repeatedly divides the input until it's not even or zero. Then it returns whether it's equal to 1 (if it's a 1, then it's a power of -2).

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
AĖuḌ@$Ƈ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWqx2PTCt9uKPHQeVY-5LipORiqPiCRboWEBYA)

##### Explanation

```python
AĖuḌ@$Ƈ  # Implicit input       ->  -8
A        # Absolute value       ->  8
 Ė       # Push [0..n]          ->  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  uḌ     # Push -2              ->  [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]  2
    @    # Exponentiate         ->  [1,-2,4,-8,16,-32,64,-128,256]
     $Ƈ  # Contains the input?  ->  1
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì´J Åx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=7LRKIMV4&input=LTIwNDg)