# Is it a completely even number?

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem

A completely even number is a positive even integer whose divisors (not including 1) are all even.

Some completely even numbers are:

- 2 (divisors: 2, 1)
- 4 (divisors: 4, 2, 1)
- 16 (divisors: 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)
- 128 (divisors: 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1).

Some *non*-completely even numbers are:

- 10 (divisors: 10, 5, 2, 1)
- 12 (divisors: 12, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1)
- 14 (divisors: 14, 7, 2, 1)
- 18 (divisors: 18, 9, 6, 3, 2, 1)
- 1, being odd, is not completely even.

0 is not completely even (it's divisible by all positive integers, including odd numbers) but you **do not** need to handle this.

Your challenge is to take a positive integer as input and output a truthy value if it is completely even and a falsy value if it is not. These outputs do not need to be consistent.

If your solution doesn't return a falsy value for 0, it's encouraged to show what changes would be necessary to make it do so. Especially encouraged is to **show how your solution differs from checking if the input is a power of 2**; in some languages it may be shorter, and in some longer.

Input may be taken via any allowed method, and output may be given via any allowed method.

The shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17456/71256)

Comment: This is powers of 2 (credit to El'endia Starman in chat for pointing it out)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115516/48934), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/115573/48934).

Comment: @Xcali that one is closed, and this one doesn't have the [tag:restricted-source]

Comment: For those who might be able to implement: The sum of this number's binary digits will always equal 1

Comment: @mbomb007 I fixed it.

Comment: @MDXF I meant in a way that a user searching for the challenge could find it.

Comment: @mbomb007 ah, I see. Fixed.

Comment: I know this has been repeated ad nauseam, but the challenge does *not* merely ask for powers of two. **2⁰ = 1**, so **1** is a power of two, yet not completely even.

Comment: @mbomb007 See above.

Comment: @Dennis, the question contradicts itself. By the definition given in the first paragraph, 1 is completely even, because its divisors except 1 form an empty set and so are trivially all even.

Comment: Yeah, it really is the powers of 2. So I think it should be a generic "powers of 2" challenge, which we don't yet have.

Comment: @mbomb007 That would invalidate all existing answers.

Comment: @mbomb007 / Dennis I'll ask a new question sometime later today. If that's generally accepted.

Comment: Reopen voters, please read comments before voting. The question hasn't been edited to not contradict itself, so it is unclear and should still be closed. That it's not possible to change the close reason without reopening is a flaw in the system, but just reopening questions which need fixing is not the solution.

Comment: This is still the closest thing to a pure "powers of 2" question on the whole site... and it asks you to return falsey for 1. Damnit. But this would be a good question, worthy of having positive votes, if only there were *also* a plain "powers of 2" question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Óg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8OT0//8NAQ)

In 05AB1E only `1` is truthy. Input-`1`-and-input-`0`-verified.

Answer (score 13):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
qB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v9Dp/39DAA)

#### How it works

This takes advantage of MATL's convenient interpretation of truthy and falsy. `q` decrements the input and `B` gets the binary representation of the result. This yields a non-empty array of **1**'s (truthy) for even powers of two, an array that is either empty of contains a **0** (falsy) otherwise.

Comment: Throws an error for `0`.

Comment: Which makes the output empty and thus falsy.

Comment: Is this an allowed output format? Why should 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 be considered falsy and not truthy?

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
^’>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/uUcNMu/8GRYYGBgYKh9sPT0hTiFR4uGP7o4Y5Cj6ZxSXFCok5OQrJ@bkFOaklqTmVCqllqXkKeaW5SalFxQpJqSXlqUC@gUJiXooCyAy9/wA)

#### How it works

```
^’>  Main link. Argument: n

 ’   Decrement; yield n-1.
^    Compute the bitwise XOR of n and n-1.
     This will conserve the highest set bit of n only if n is a power of two.
     If n is even, n-1 will be positive and the result will be different from n.
  >  Test if the result is larger than n.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 16 bytes

```python
lambda n:n^n-1>n
```

Returns *True* or *False*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5fUJSZV6KhlZaZU5JapPE/JzE3KSVRIc8qLy5P19Au77@OQlFiXnqqhqGBgYGmpuZ/AA)

#### How it works

- If **n = 0**, then **n ⊕ (n - 1) = 0 ⊕ -1 = -1 < 0 = n**, so the function returns *False*.
- If **n = 1**, then **n ⊕ (n - 1) = 1 ⊕ 0 = 1 = n**, so the function returns *False*.
- If **2<sup>k</sup> < n < 2<sup>k+1</sup>**, then **2<sup>k</sup> ≤ n - 1 < 2<sup>k+1</sup>**, so **n** and **n - 1** have the **2<sup>k</sup>** bit in common,
  **n ⊕ (n - 1) < 2<sup>k</sup> < n**, and the function returns *False*.
- Finally, if **n = 2<sup>k</sup>** with **k > 0**, then **n = 2<sup>k</sup>** and **n - 1 = 2<sup>k</sup> - 1** have no bits in common, so
  **n ⊕ (n - 1) = n + (n - 1) > n + 0 = n** and the function returns *True*.

Answer (score 6):

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 17 bytes

`^((x+)(?=\2$))+x$` - Completely even

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc89b8IwFIXhv0IjBPeSJiQIdcA1TB1YGNqxtJIVLs5tjWPZBlI@fnsKQ6XOz5GO3i91UKHy7GIWHG/I7xr7TT@dl5aOvVfSL60DOMn5eNR9ArQpwkKuJ33EtO13o/EJ89i8Rc9WA@bBcEXw9JhNEUWQhTjWbAjASE9qY9gSID5IuzcGz1qaPDjDEYbZEAVvAazUuSGrY43zyeXCYaVWwNIpH2hpI@j34gPxD@g/2Hm5KGd3xlj75pgs7UEZ3vS8sppmvSQ1Ytt4EPwsSXCa4u0waZPckyMVgTHfqVjV4BHPYTBwt6QI94pSuH0M0d8m4nrtimxaFsUv) - ECMAScript

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Na8JAEIb/igRhZ4hZEunJ7eqpBy8e2mNtcUnGOCXdpLOrBtTfnsZCwdsLz/v15U4ulMJdzHxb0RBsbsS@Uv3Sd/AWhX2txZ13wydAnyKs7HY@RUz76bDToeGSoJhlBaIR@jmyECghVzXsSaEuRx1p7SPJ3o3WC/vuGBedtCWFoEOs2N9Qtx7UX2LW2OWlto0OXcMRVKbQ8B7A21o35Ot4wOX8euWwcRtg2zkJ93ao3/MPxH9Aj8Avi1WxuGOMB2nPydqfXMPVRJyvaTFJ0sbsWwHDz5YMpymOg0mfaKFuPA@M@tvF8gCCeHk43h6jPgtHAggrtfVqoRSmjCbYwtxuOOTZU5Hnvw) - ECMAScript 2018**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbbtswDH3vV3BGh0i5qE6xp6lGsQ0bMGDthvYxzQDFlhOlMu1JcuOm6LdnlONdCtQvNMmjQ50jbtWDmm2L@4OpmtoF2FIuTC3GEv6vtMHYV2tOr3VHnZOmXVmTQ26V93ClDMITDDUfVKDwUJsCKuqw2@AMrkG5tV8sOYSNq3cePne5boKp6eQJwBdjNZQZ6l3/yxKR14UW1E@4/NiWpXa6uNGq0A5WPexlkf05OaQl53KY66dB7jaRnzGfrUiDKr4Z1IzzNxm21nJTMi/0r1ZZz5Kz8XiccP70EnpkYCy8SvBEDOEvAxGcEcOKcPfST7LRHY5iDPL5WHv@oULQDsFlwx@prZo4wHNJbqzq2mqFsM9KYtQSbnOFSNINNm2ADKLaocZuH33QlTDIJQw6e5jYKH@tu0DX7C0GGAyxdHfiOIKQEIPEob9YgqV2RAnfWBNYMqNHIHwATKnzFQOtgRONcl5TwuwiXfIp4PzVprAa12FzcQ6XEJHwnsJ8SYz5RrnFshv09BnOlxI@OKcevSiNtaybjrpRbwpAWbuoja6RYSoBLzKcU5hMSOCVCvmGHKqIzYnqmLF@c5EW/BORHzdG7Jxq2DAir5vH7@WNwrWmSekUOY9KS2AVjceCvItvu@eDyTU5tnMmaBYflct9Flwb3@dfuyEPQ8mStz4hS7h8jt9J3KrDT8a6CWeX2d35KeeT7vQQV@WQzt7N0/Q3) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/ykUuNpe2NJHtxTRawb36tLfpgg4LgUy7pIOOEL96FzthL5d7zv1zft3Z2efx8wfQSQj2@nG0gJVMUtXbzetmFaG9OoZecVmvJAUwbVIUOmcuPcz2l5mM0FjlO2t6lpVZ4b9Pvk8nuihFIej8dV9a/7s8@bRETfL@y6fEo2tsvaDQ2DdxUKnyg3zkmodEU6tpnLo8p2BaYCwbMhggLRGBukGFrqKAfj6f4Ca2BC7kHysaGWPU@mW31Xp8Z2zIia3VfoFE@YDjyMsnwfkv) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda4MwFH3vrwghYO7UVqXbKKn0ZRsUxh62vdUuWBdrmI0hpiCU/nZ3LXvaQy7365xzc2xjx/XGNpYwR3JCF5TMiXXqKJ2ybVkpHizmdxspm7L1supOVrfKFbwAUbwv@iAiAb4am/KopgXjlfE9l/Jl@/osJUQkBaREYjHTRsteeU5t5dT8UFY/3mGQrT5pTyNCl9lquXp4zFb3FMSs7hxnOk8Ea/Ma2Xv@8fm0fQMBF6Jrztpd712rDGYQp/s8p4WhgMv9@YATbEdJFKcw4dVg2@5bcRrTCNcF4qvubPyEXWcI2iEBxmQvZoTclM1fzcw6v80xC0NAacJvDp1KXzWcuQjFJrtU6XkwBBEzAEAu04kaVNV0012C4FdSQaaaMCOuKHP9ZysHMX5xPoTAN3mRMYBwYOOYxMs0SX4B) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNdb5swFH3Pr7jLqsYu0EIq7QFCK03aH5j2sClNEXUcsJYYyxjlY@pfb3ZtGkYz4gew78e595xrM6WCgrHjZyHZullymL1UVW3uNC/47rZU6mF07uI7xpURlbxbiryQaBIsE3JV6U1uzW0WK3MNmZovIIXv46/b7e@X@@bXfv/zR/llW5LjMyE7j5LH9Gl6Ram3uzrS86CxDzcqzZQXJb0mBBbUPN88jIQ0sMmFJBT@jACXmqNrzSVRNIgWaZhAgzH308xAZU82obCb2izjGGOFLNCoGpO4fFbJ2oBjGcdOAdAcwZKTrUaGrIRtmb9nIGkgFvaQhj4ceAdecLMWkhN3YEL6bR2anHq1yybKEAXKTSWIC7hlGfZFKPVBRj6oqkZ361kJuSSTYEKTDkBG6LUxn9I@pziW1vg4gAuei/cgohBj8X9YbmA3tpzk2/Y0l5EXLRLY8E3NDal9mOwmtjFUpEanlbjL76QQqbRaz1IZJeB5os/YLqP3ZxanxQpIX/ms5rlmJSE9XvTaVg3Ewncj8HE6lA5gnfAOFJC6pUImTxKFwzFFyWB4O6eqMTCbgfg/5nV0@cTcpSAfbk/3SOCaa00vEB5u8KwZ@xnH8E3rSo@TYRxOYWWRHIxvAWzVxN7IDg8tfbyx/b93O/yQicO4QLzdtV/NTaMl4GV4PYbBNArDN7Za50V9DNauQuZG@hc) - Boost
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NasMwEITvfopF5LBb/yC5N7uiD@I4EFqlUVFXZqUQ5@mdKKG3YT6@YZZbPkd@3/zfEiVDuqVGXPObIo8gVpRS2wFxrQk/7b7fEdXrbnu0kxlaM4/gra5OUSCA52J3KX97HioINnRpCT6jahVV4E8QHGOgj36AMJnZhknPFRSZiyxH/nHoOWMB1LySmak29NgrA@K65I7ydUZpQK3qjZ@kID/AIkWhZ2HN@P8mXnJ3FZ8dpizIRJtue6P1HQ) - Python**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BC8IwDIXv/oo4BFtlodu1FhH06kG8TS2KdRZKHF3FefGvz1bUQwJ5ed9L/P307D0o2JjadA2SecBysV2gN8ezBKuEhMfVOgNO1Sa0AwB7AVflxV6pbEeZjAtXCcS83EswdI6OqGDbOBvYOB/zL4LOUB2ujM/KyFSRj9gfudw8EFiCJGK4acsKwRGT8T9G3yeLZV02IQ7qBV4mwQ7Tn809tJ@89HcRZ28pAP1OpJ5K69V6qXV/YKybcjZXu3LE@bQb9b3Iy0KINw) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RaoQwFER/ReSCSdMs0ccNoQt97hdYC8HerYHsjcQsykq@3WpL6eMZhsPMGGaM04DebxBNG/ELl@58JpzZpdo@GFsEZy/mvQHOxQJbdXkuX8NtdB4/S67hYZS@hoi2Hxj4wlEBjsZ74itYA15Oo3eplKV2Vwb21Ic7JelT0RwFYcC2qsu7gAGZ1lHqfhINJD3@cX2wEHw9HPH0ZlM/4MSqpXoC4r/xg69zdAnlEKaU91m1/udCUtgfeUdYAOWcNyWbWqlv) - .NET

Remarkably, there are *three* completely different 17 byte solutions for Powers of 2, which blew my mind even when I thought there were two. For this challenge, only one is 17 bytes, but for plain Powers of 2 they all are.

---

`^(?!(x(xx)+)\1*$)` - **17 bytes** - Powers of 2
`^(?!(x(xx)+)\1*$)x` - **18 bytes** - Powers of 2, correct at zero
`^(?!(x(xx)+)\1*$)xx` - **19 bytes** - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ECMAScript | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc/LbsIwEIXhV4GogpmkCUmFusA1rLpgw6Jd9iJZZHCmNY5lG0i5PHsKi0pdf0c6@r/UXoW1Zxfz4Lgmv23tN/30Xlo6DF5IP3cO4Cjnk7T/hMUQOug6zPC9Su@wTydHLGL7Gj1bDVgEw2uCx/t8iiiCLMWhYUMARnpStWFLgDiUdmcMnrQ0RXCGI4zzMQreAFipC0NWxwbnD@czh5VaAUunfKCljaDfyg/EP6D/YOfVoprdGGPj20OytHtluB54ZTXNBklmxKb1IPhJkuAsw@th0iWFJ0cqAmOxVXHdgEc8hdHIXZMi3Coq4XYxRH@diMulr/JpVZa/) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc/LbsIwEIXhV4GoghnShKRCXeAaVl2wYdEue5EsGJxpjWPZBlwuz57ColLX35GO/i@1V2Hl2cUiOF6T37b2m346Ly0dei@kn5MDOMrZeNR9wrwPCVLCHN/r0R2m1I3GRyxj@xo9Ww1YBsMrgsf7YoIogqzEoWFDAEZ6UmvDlgCxL@3OGDxpacrgDEcYFkMUvAGwUpeGrI4Nzh7OZw5LtQSWTvlACxtBv1UfiH9A/8HO6nk9vTHGxreHbGH3yvC655XVNO1luRGb1oPgJ0mC8xyvh1nKSk@OVATGcqviqgGPeAqDgbsmRbhV1MLtYoj@OhGXS1cVk7qqfgE) |
| Python | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BTsMwEETv@YrF6mG3TaIscEqw@iEhSBW4rZFZR2ujpl@f1kXcRvP0RjNf8znKy@p/5qgZ0jXV6urvFGUAtWqMWT9w/4QLLgvt6J23G1rv7ch9w9MA3nbVMSoE8FLsNuUvL30FwYY2zcFnNI2hCvwRghMM9PbcQxh5smHspgqKLEXWg5wceslYANV/iSfaMd33yoC6NrmDfp5RazCL2cqDFOR7mLUo9CgsD/9v4m9uL@qzw5QVhWjl5pW77gY) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BTsMwEETv@YrF6mG3TSIbOCVY/ZAQpArc1siso7VR3a9P6yJuo3l6o1mu@Rz5ZfU/S5QM6Zpace13ijyCWFFKrR@4f8KCpdCO3s12Q6Ws934yQ2fmEbzVzTEKBPBc/T7lL89DA8GGPi3BZ1Sdogb8EYJjDPT2PECYzGzDpOcGqsxVlgOfHHrOWAG1f8nMtDN036sD4vrkDvJ5RmlBFbXlB6nID7BIVehRWDP@v4m/ub@Izw5TFmSiVXevRusb) |
| Ruby | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BiwIxDIXv/oo4LNgqE1rZW7eI4F73IHsbtSjWsVDi0KnYvfjXZ1tRDwnk5X0vCdfD3xBAw9q2NnVI9gar5e8Sg90fFTgtFNzOzlvwurWxHwG4E/imllutqw1VKi98IxDr@VaBpWN2ZAX7zrvIJvWEPxH0ltp4Zvxrnpkm8xl7I6dLAAJHUESMF@OYFByxGN9j9j2yWJWqKXHQdwiqCG5c/uyusX/klb9lnoOjCPQ6UXopY75/VsYMO7YYs8RS4jO@kdMPPgyy/pRC/AM) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BiwIxDIXv/oo4LNgqE1rZW7eI4F73IHsbtSjWsVDi0KnYvfjXZ1tRDwnk5X0vCdfD3xBAw9q2NnVI9gar5e8Sg90fFTgtFNzOzlvwurWxHwG4E/imllutqw1VKi98IxDr@VaBpWN2ZAX7zrvIJvWEPxH0ltp4Zvxrnpkm8xl7I6dLAAJHUESMF@OYFByxGN9j9j2yWJWqKXHQdwiqCG5c/uyusX/klb9lnoOjCPQ6UXopY75/VsYMO7YYs8RS4jO@kdMPntIwiPpTCvEP) |

This is what I came up to solve a level of [Regex Golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf) on 2014-02-21, and was also independently discovered by several others, including earlier than 2013-12-20. It's the one most similar to the well-known [primality test](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57617/is-this-number-a-prime/177196#177196), which is probably why most people came up with this one instead of the others.

It asserts that \$n\$ has no odd divisors of \$3\$ or greater yielding a positive quotient. It has a false positive for zero, since although zero can be divided by any odd number, the quotient is zero, not positive. This can be fixed at the cost of an extra byte: `^(?!(x(xx)+|)\1*$)` or `^(?!(x(xx)+)\1*$)x`.

Since the entire test is inside a (negative) lookahead, it can be adapted to answer this challenge by adding `xx` at the end, which enforces that only \$n≥2\$ can match.

---

`^(?!(x*)(\1\1)+$)` - **17 bytes** - Powers of 2
`^(?!(x*)(\1\1)+$)xx` - **19 bytes** - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ECMAScript | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc/LbsIwEIXhVwlRBTNJE5IKdYFrWHXBhkW7LK1kweBMaxzLNpdyefYUFpVYf0c6@r/VToWlZxeL4HhFftPaH/rtvLS0T95Ivx4cwFFOhln3BdMeHDKERb2oMX/ALhsesYzte/RsNWAZDC8Jnh@LEaIIshL7hg0BGOlJrQxbAsSetFtj8KSlKYMzHGFQDFDwGsBKXRqyOjY4eTqfOczVHFg65QPNbAT9UX0i/gPdg53U03p8Y4yNb/fpzO6U4VXildU0TtLciHXrQfCLJMF5jtfD9JCWnhypCIzlRsVlAx7xFPp9d02KcKuohdvGEP11Ii6XripGdVX9AQ) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5PT8IwGMa/ChKTvq9jzWo8rRZOHrhw0KNoaLaX8ZrazbbAEuCzz2Fiwu1Jfs@/L3uwsQrcpdy3NQ3RFDqYV2pe@g7eUmDfyGCPm@ETFnfQPyCs1Vphdo99P2xkdFwRqFmuEHWgnz0HAhHI1o49CZTVqBMtfaKwtaP1xL7bp7ILbUUxyphq9heUrQfxl5g5Mz81xsnYOU4gcoGatwDeNNKRb9IO54/nM8eVXQGbzoZ4bYfmvfhA/Ad0C/xcLVR5xZh2oT1Ol/5gHdeTYH1D5WSaOb1tA2h@NqQ5y3AcnPZTGagbzwOj/Lap2kFAPN0cb/dJHgMnAogLsfaiFAIzRh2N0pcLDkX@pIriFw) |
| Python | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BTsMwEETv@YrF4rDbJpFdbglWPyQNUgUuXWTW0doV7deHuojbaJ7eaJZbOSd5Wfl7SVog33Krof3KSUZQr8aY9Q33T3jdEB7cwdH2mdZ7O7mhc/MI7G1zSgoRWKrd5/LBMjQQfezzErmg6Qw1wCeIQTDS626AOLnZx8nODVRZqqxH@QzIUrACav@Sm2nr6L5XBzT0ORz1/YzagrmajTxIRTzAolWhR@Hd@P8mXUr/o1wC5qIoRKvtds7aXw) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BTsMwEETv@YrF4rDbJpFdbgkWH5IGqQKXLjLraG1E@vWhLuI2mqc3muVaLkmeNv5akhbI19xqaD9zkhHUqzFme8WXB1x3hEd3dLR/pHXdbv3khs7NI7C3zTkpRGCpfp/LO8vQQPSxz0vkgqYz1ACfIQbBSM@HAeLkZh8nOzdQZamynuQjIEvBCqj9S26mvaPbXh3Q0Odw0rcLagtmNTu5k4p4gEWrQvfCu/H/Tfou/Y9yCZiLohBttjs4a38B) |
| Ruby | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Bi8IwEIXv/oqxLJgoHZJes2ER9LqHxVurQWmsgTCWNGL34l/vJrJ6mIF58743E26n3ymAhh/b2bFHsnfYrHdrDPbYKnBaKLhfnLfgdWfjMANwZ/B1KfdaFw0VKi18LRDLaq/AUpscScGh9y6yRbng/wh6S128MP5ZJaZOfMLeyPkagMARZBHj1TgmBUfMxveYfM8sVozFkjjoBwSVBTfPf/a3ODzz8t8yzcFRBHqdyD2XMdvvjTHTgX3N2bjkrJGN5KsPPk2irKQQfw) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BawIxEIXv/RXjIpgoOyR7jUEEvXoove3aUDGugTAu2YjppX99m0jrYQbmzfveTLifvqcAGt5tb9OAZB@w235sMdivswKnhYLH1XkLXvc2jm8A7gK@reVR66qjSuWFbwVi3RwVWDpnR1ZwHLyLbFEv@B@C3lIfr4yvm8y0mc/YC7ncAhA4giJivBnHpOCIxfgas@@ZxapULYmD/oGgiuBm5c/hHsdnXvlb5jk4ikD/J0ovZcz@sDNm@mSbGUtLzjrZSb6a85SmSdSNFOIX) |

This was discovered by Grimmy in 2019-02-05, [without fanfare](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48931239#48931239). I on the other hand was amazed, as this has no such flaw as the other negative assertion – it does not match zero.

It asserts that \$n\$ has no divisors yielding an odd quotient of \$3\$ or greater. As a negative assertion, it does not consume the power of 2 that it matches, and thus is great for use in larger regexes where it doesn't need to be wrapped in a lookahead to allow other tests to be done on the same value of \$tail\$.

The downside is that in standard regex engines, it's significantly slower than `^(?!(x(xx)+|)\1*$)`. In my regex engine though, they're both [statically optimized](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/blob/master/matcher-optimization.h#L148) into a bitwise power of 2 test unless optimizations are disabled.

---

`^((x+)(?=\2$))*x$` - **17 bytes** - Powers of 2
`^((x+)(?=\2$))+x$` - **17 bytes** - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ECMAScript | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc89b8IwFIXhv0IjBPeSJiQIdcA1TB1YGNqxtJIVLs5tjWPZBlI@fnsKQ6XOz5GO3i91UKHy7GIWHG/I7xr7TT@dl5aOvVfSL60DOMn5eNR9ArQpwkKuJ33EUdvvRuMT5rF5i56tBsyD4Yrg6TGbIoogC3Gs2RCAkZ7UxrAlQHyQdm8MnrU0eXCGIwyzIQreAlipc0NWxxrnk8uFw0qtgKVTPtDSRtDvxQfiH9B/sPNyUc7ujLH2zTFZ2oMyvOl5ZTXNeklqxLbxIPhZkuA0xdth0ia5J0cqAmO@U7GqwSOew2DgbkkR7hWlcPsYor9NxPXaFdm0LIpf) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc89b8IwFIXhv0IjBPeSJiQIdcA1TB1YGNqxtJIVLs5tjWPZBlI@fnsKQ6XOz5GO3i91UKHy7GIWHG/I7xr7TT@dl5aOvVfSL60DOMn5eNR9ArQpwkKuJ33EtO13o/EJ89i8Rc9WA@bBcEXw9JhNEUWQhTjWbAjASE9qY9gSID5IuzcGz1qaPDjDEYbZEAVvAazUuSGrY43zyeXCYaVWwNIpH2hpI@j34gPxD@g/2Hm5KGd3xlj75pgs7UEZ3vS8sppmvSQ1Ytt4EPwsSXCa4u0waZPckyMVgTHfqVjV4BHPYTBwt6QI94pSuH0M0d8m4nrtimxaFsUv) |
| Python | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BbsIwEETv@YqVxWEXkshOb0ktPiQECbWmGLnraG1E@PqAqXobzdMbzfzIl8gfq/@do2RIj1SLq68p8gBiRSm1HhGXHeHeHroN0XbZrK92NH1jpgG81dU5CgTwXOw25W/PfQXBhjbNwWdUjaIK/BmCYwz02fUQRjPZMOqpgiJzkeXEPw49ZyyA6r9kJtoZeu2VAXFtcif5uqDUoBa15TcpyPcwS1HoXVgz/L@Jt9zexWeHKQsy0aqbzmj9BA) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NasMwEITvfopF5LBb/yC5N7uiD@I4EFqlUVFXZqUQ5@mdKKG3YT6@YZZbPkd@3/zfEiVDuqVGXPObIo8gVpRS2wFxrQk/7b7fEdXrbnu0kxlaM4/gra5OUSCA52J3KX97HioINnRpCT6jahVV4E8QHGOgj36AMJnZhknPFRSZiyxH/nHoOWMB1LySmak29NgrA@K65I7ydUZpQK3qjZ@kID/AIkWhZ2HN@P8mXnJ3FZ8dpizIRJtue6P1HQ) |
| Ruby | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BC8IwDIXv/oo4BFtlodu1FhH06kG8TS2KdRZKHF3FefGvz1bUQwJ5ed9L/P307D0o2JjadA2SecBysV2gN8ezBKuEhMfVOgNO1Sa0AwB7AVflxV6pbEeZjAtXCcS83EswdI6OqGDbOBvYOB/zL4LOUB2ujM/KyFSRj9gfudw8EFiCJGK4acsKwRGT8T9G3yeLZV02IQ7qBV4mwQ7Tn809tJ@89HcRZ28pAP1OpJ5K69V6qXV/YKybcjZXu3LE@aQb9b3Iy0KINw) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BC8IwDIXv/oo4BFtlodu1FhH06kG8TS2KdRZKHF3FefGvz1bUQwJ5ed9L/P307D0o2JjadA2SecBysV2gN8ezBKuEhMfVOgNO1Sa0AwB7AVflxV6pbEeZjAtXCcS83EswdI6OqGDbOBvYOB/zL4LOUB2ujM/KyFSRj9gfudw8EFiCJGK4acsKwRGT8T9G3yeLZV02IQ7qBV4mwQ7Tn809tJ@89HcRZ28pAP1OpJ5K69V6qXV/YKybcjZXu3LE@bQb9b3Iy0KINw) |

I discovered this one in 2014-02-21, after being mentally primed by solving teukon's Dominoes 2 puzzle (which is now included in [Regex Golf](https://alf.nu/RegexGolf)); teukon independently came up with it later that same day. It was the very first problem in unary that we solved by repeatedly decreasing \$tail\$ in a loop while retaining an invariant property at every step, and is probably the simplest function that is best golfed by being solved that way.

It repeatedly divides \$tail\$ by \$2\$ (asserting each time that there is no remainder) as many times as possible, and then asserts that the end result is \$1\$. This one is useful in larger regexes when it is desirable to consume the identified power of 2.

It is the most suitable for solving this challenge, “Is it a completely even number?”, as the only change necessary is upping the minimum iteration count of the loop from `0` to `1` by changing the `*` quantifier to a `+`, at a cost of 0 bytes. This enforces that \$n\$ must be evenly divided by \$2\$ at least once before yielding an end result of \$1\$.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 18 bytes

```python
lambda x:~-x&x<1<x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqk63Qq3CxtCm4n9BUWZeiUKaRmZeQWmJhqbmf0MA)

-3 thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod).

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), 14 bytes

```js
f=
n=>n>1>(n&n-1)
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Python doesn't have the monopoly on chained comparisons!

Comment: This might be the first time I've ever seen JS's comparison chaining come in handy in a function this short...

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 6 bytes

```
õ!² øU
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SGyIPhV&input=MQ==)

---

### Explanation

Generate an array of integers (`õ`) from `1` to input `U`. Raise 2 to the power of each (`!²`). Check if the array includes (`ø`) `U`.

Comment: [Get outgolfed 6 years later](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259844/108687)

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

Returns `log₂(x)` if True `0` otherwise

```
£İ2
```

#### Explanation

```
£       Is it an element of the increasing sequence
 İ2     powers of two (starting at 2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9DiIxuM/v//b2hkAQA)

Comment: Are all positive integers truthy in Husk?

Comment: Yes, and negative integers too

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda n:bin(n).count('1')==1-n%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKikzTyNPUy85vzSvREPdUF3T1tZQN08VqCq/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9RA06qgKDOvRCFTJ00jU/M/AA)

### Recusive approach, <s>38</s> 36 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun</sup>

```python
f=lambda n:n>1if n<3else f(~n%2*n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq8wm0Agqo41UdzFyasC@Ym7adHV7L73lijC18hrcvR@OYLGNwoRl8uHxxOpDY1r0RleOmYQElB1Or@ZB25QFhaRjJbr@)

Comment: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEAXQq8wmUAgqo41UdzFyasC@Ym06/dRbvfI@Z4ZT5SWFa9sDwWMdhAnzGNMdiQ0alyuhc1b5j5CAasARzdRbX6rgIWnZiNUP)

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQq8wm0Agqo41UdzFyasC@Ym7adHV7L73lijC18hrcvR@OYLGNwoRl8uHxxOpDY1r0RleOmYQElB1Or@ZB25QFhaRjJbr@)

Comment: You have `lambda n` but you use variable `i`.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere my bad, fixed

Answer (score 3):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), <s>7</s> <s>2</s>  3 bytes

```
½?ö
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@///QXvvD2/7/NwQA) Explanation:

```
     implicit float input
½    calculate log2(input)
 ?   if truthy
  ö   push 1 if top-of-stack is whole, 0 if non-whole
     implicit int output
```

`½` pushes log2(input). If the input is `0` or `1` it will push `0.000000`. 0 is a whole number so performing `ö` on 0 will yield 1, giving the incorrect result for the input 1. `?` only performs the next command if the top of stack is truthy. So if the input was 1 or 0, it will skip the `ö` and print 0 as it's supposed to. Otherwise it will push 1 if `log2(input)` is whole and 0 if it's not.

Answer (score 3):

## Regex ([Tcl ARE](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

`^((x((xx)*))\2*$)\3` - **19 bytes** - Powers of 2 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbisIwEH33K46hD1YotC7sS7f7I5qFWscajGNJ4loo/fbutG5Flh3yMJk5l3ASKjt4CnDY@tveByR8ra6XS8kHP/b7sjp7W/oTTdfv0plyb@XSDV@rVSunjddxvNuso3j3NvQ6xywXnOEaruSaEDlk2FLbOHTzxhLX4SQrjQSbXuvFyDTIctxPxpIgawoePhwMw2osCyRZj24BqRFrrdg01gREFipRYm6OQrOztBXWJ9KZM/M4xdYaPlA7QpD@yysKjGYTPkPEokLW03PyqpDp/mlwvLpfzIPURYyPQvpRzXDlwK/vGWsyd1RLPkhE1VQSsESmniFSQ2WAmLFW@i99llhGRlbNTTJTqs8faaY5pol8HtNd3kxQEateakiT9zT9AQ)
`^(x$|(x((xx)*))\2*$)\3` - **22 bytes** - Completely even - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLboMwELznKyaWDxAJCVKpF0p/JHElQjbEqmOQ7TRIlG@nCylRVHVP6915rMahMqOnAIedvx58QGKbqrlcSnv0U38oq09vSn@m@flVOl0eDD/68SPq5HfURVHXxZs43m83Mt6/jIPKsSgGp20NV9qaIB0y7KhrHfplY8jW4cwrhQTbQanVxNTIctzO2hAjawoePhy1hVFYF0iyAf0KXBPWGLZpjQ6QBiIRbK5PTDOLtGHWO9KFs/Bsip3R9kjdBEH6L68oMJnN@AzSsgoZT4/Js0KmhofBqXG/mDuplxZvBfeTmraVg32@Z6rZ3FHN@SBhVV1xxhyZeIRILZUBbGaVUH/pi8Raal61V85MiCG/p5nmmCf8f5ZufDNBSCsGrjFNXtP0Bw)

Tcl ARE has both positive and negative lookaheads, but neither backreferences nor captures can be done inside one. So seemingly, it would be impossible to match powers of 2 instead of non-powers, because all of the ECMAScript regexes use backreferences inside a lookahead. This challenge states "output a truthy value if it is completely even and a falsy value if it is not", so an inverted-logic regex, such as `^(x*)(\1\1)+$|^x$`, would not satisfy the rules.

But as it so happens, in Tcl ARE it seems that any group anchored on both sides (`^` at the beginning and `$` at the end, either inside or outside the group as long as it's adjacent to the parentheses) in all its alternatives will be treated as atomic (preventing the engine from doing the equivalent of backtracking into that expression if the pattern fails to match at a later point). This does not appear to be documented, but it can be exploited to emulate a negative match. The equivalent in engines that support atomic groups would be:

`^(?>(x((xx)*))\1*$)\2` - **21 bytes** - Powers of 2 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH33V4QQaK6m2ha3IbHzZRsIYw/b3qwLtUttWU1DGqEg/vbuVva0h1zu1znn5tjKDuuNrSxhjqSELiiZE@v0UTltm7zQPFjMpxulqrzxqmhPtm60y3gGMntfdIEgAb4Sm@qoxwXjtfEdV@pl@/qsFAgSA1IisZzUplad9pzawun5IS9@vMOgmvpUeyoIXSar5er@IVndUZCTsnWc1WkkWZOWyN7xj8@n7RtIuJC65KzZdd412mAGYbxPU5oZCrjcnQ84wbaIRBjDiNe9bdpvzWlIBa5LxBft2fgRu04QtEMCjNFeTgi5KZu/mpl1eptjNpsBShN@c@iU@6LizAkUG@3SuedBHwhmAIBcxhNr0EXVjndJgl@JJRlrwoy8osz1n60c5PDFN4@857zvYQqQxVMGWTIMUZjEUfQL)
`^(?>(x\B((xx)*))\1*$)\2` - **23 bytes** - Completely even - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdS8MwFH3frwgh0Nyt3doylZHVgaggiA/q2zpDV9O1mKUhzaAw9tvr7fDJh1zu1znn5tjaDuuNrS1hjmSELiiZE@vUQTpldVEqHizm042UdaG9LNujbbRyOc9B5O@LLghJgK/CpjyoccF4ZXzHpXx@eX2SEkKSAFIisZg0ppGd8pza0qn5vih/vMMgdXNsPA0JXaar5er2Ll3dUBCTqnWcNVksmM4qZO/4x@fjyxsIOJOm4kxvO@@0MphBlOyyjOaGAi53pz1OsB3GYZTAiFe91e234jSiIa4LxJftyfgRu04RtEUCjPFOTAi5Kpu/mpl1dp1jNpsBShN@dehY@LLmzIUoNtqlCs@DPgiZAQByHk9sQJV1O94lCH4lEWSsCTPigjKXf7ZyEMMX39zzPn/gvO9hCpAnUwZ5OgxxlCZx/As)

These in turn are based on the [17 byte ECMAScript regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222496/17216) `^(?!(x(xx)+)\1*$)`. The logic of the Tcl ARE version is to assert that the largest odd factor of \$n\$ is \$1\$. The "completely even" version additionally asserts than \$n\ne 1\$.

Even more strangely than the atomic grouping behavior, Tcl ARE apparently records the positions where word-boundary-match operators (`\m`, `\M`, `\y`, `\Y`) were used inside a capture group, and repeats them if that group is repeated via a backreference. So `^((x\Y((xx)*))\2*$)\3` (**21 bytes**) not only doesn't match \$1\$, but doesn't match \$2\$ either: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLasMwELznKybChzhgsFPoxXX/oyQqOM7GEVU2RlIag/G3u2unDqF0D2K1Ow8xCpUdPAU4bP117wMSvlSX87nkgx/7fVl9eVv6E03X79KZcm/l0g2fq1W7@5CjjddxvNuso3j3MvQ6xywYnOEaruSaEDlk2FLbOHTzxhLX4SQrjQSbXuvFyDTIctxOxpIgawoePhwMw2osCyRZj24BqRFrrdg01gREFipRYm6OQrOztBXWO9KZM/M4xdYaPlA7QpD@yysKjGYTPkPEokLW02PyrJDp/mFwvLhfzJ3URYy3QvpRzXDlwM/vGWsyd1RLPkhE1VQSsUSmHiFSQ2WAmLFW@i99llhGRlbNVTJTqs/vaaY5pol8H9NN3kxQEateakiT1zT9AQ) – and as a result, the 22 byte method has to be used instead.

Explanation for Powers of 2 (**19 bytes**):

```
^
(                  # Group an expression that is anchored to start at its
                   # beginning and to end at its end, thus telling the Tcl ARE
                   # regex engine to treat it as atomic, not backtracking into
                   # it if a subsequent match fails.
    (              # \2 = sum of the following, which will be the largest odd
                   #      number that results in a match for what follows:
        x          # 1; tail -= 1
        ((xx)*)    # \3 = any even number, including zero, trying the largest
                   #      values first; tail -= \3
    )
    \2*$           # Assert that \2 divides tail; anchor to end of string
)
\3                 # Now that the above match is locked in and won't backtrack,
                   # assert that \3 == 0, as no other value can match when
                   # tail == 0 (at the end of the string), thus asserting that
                   # \2 == 1, i.e. that the largest odd factor of N is 1.
```

For Completely even (**22 bytes**), an alternative of `x$` is inserted as the first choice. If \$n=1\$ and this alternative matches, it effectively acts like a boolean short-circuit operator – the powers of 2 test won't be done, and `\3` will not be set.

An alternative method to match powers of 2 is `^((x+?)((\2\2)*$))\3` (**20 bytes**): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbboJAEH33K44bHqANCeCjpf0Q3SaII266jmR3rSaEb6cDFmOaztPszLlMzobaDp4CHDb@svMBKZ/r8@lU8d6P/a6qv7yt/JGm53flTLWz8uiGzzi@vX4kcbwttkXyEiXJdjX0eo1ZLzjDDVzFDSFyyLGhW@vQzRtL3ISjrDRSFL3Wi5FpkK9xPRpLgmwoePiwNwyrsSyR5j26BaRGrLVi01oTEFmoVIm5OQjNztJWWO/IZs7M4wwba3hPtxGC7F9eWWI0m/A5IhYVsp4ek2eFXPcPg8PZ/WLupC5ivJXSj2qGawd@vmesydxRI/kgFVVTS8ISmXqESC1VAWLGWum/9FliGRlZtRfJTKl@fU8zW2OayO8xXeVmgopY9VJDlq6KHw) - this uses the same atomic grouping trick, but the logic is to assert that the smallest quotient from dividing \$n\$ by any odd number is \$n\$ (thus it's implied that the only odd divisor of \$n\$ is \$1\$). For "completely even" numbers this becomes `^(x$|(x+?)((\2\2)*$))\3` (**23 bytes**): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLboMwELznKyaWD9AKCciR0n5I4kqEuMSqs0G20yBRvp0upERR1T2td@exGofajl4HOGz9Ze8DEjrX59OpooOf@n1Vf3pb@aOen1@VM9Xe8qMf36NOfkfd81scRbt8l8dPMo53m3FQBRbJ4Aw1cBU1GtIhw1Z3rUO/bKymJhx5pZAgH5RaTUyDrMD1aKxmZKODhw8HQ7AK6xJJNqBfgWvCWss2rTUB0kIkgs3NB9PsIm2Z9Yp04Sw8SrG1hg66myBI/@WVJSazGZ9BEqto6/V98qiQqeFu8HF2v5gbqZeEl5L7Sc1Q7UCP90w1mzvdcD5IWNXUHDJHJu4h6lZXAWxGSqi/9EViLQ2v2gtnJsRQ3NJMC8wT/kDSV75ZQ0gSA9eYJpv8Bw) But this method is much slower than the primary one shown in this answer, and Tcl cannot even match \$n=64\$ within 60 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Æf=2Ȧ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW5qt0Yll////NwQA)

Does ***NOT*** fail for `1`!

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```java
i->i>1&(i&~-i)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY0xD4IwEIV3fsVNhBppwmYCMjiYODgxGocKlRyWtqFXEmLwr2MxDL7x3fe@68QoUmOl7prXgr01A0EXOk7YS77Lo//OEyr@9LomNHo9RrUSzsFVoIZ3BCGOBGEN5w0qLppkK4c9nIxRUugSLBxhwbTEMosTjD8psiJbgmudW/9QYb5ZRoMN9EGeVDSgbm93EEPr2PZrTTU5kj03nrgNCCmdWC6sVVNyYCz/cXM0L18)

Comment: This also works in JS, if you replace the "skinny arrow" with a "fat arrow": https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxP9PWLtPOUE0jU61ON1PTxvC/poahkYWm5n8A

Comment: Way better than the method based version, `i->Integer.bitCount(i+1)==1` by 11 bytes!

Comment: @corsiKa The most I could golf the method based one down to was 22 bytes: `i->i>1&i.bitCount(i)<2`. You can call a class' static methods using an instance

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>37</s> <s>33</s> <s>27</s> 18 bytes

Thanks to @MD XF for the idea

```c
f(n){n=(n^n-1)>n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjNCkBAEADg@zzFptRMOFBcBk8ipdVopwzJTZ59/XzHzxeL9zEKGl3WoY1WlNQb31EZ1ikYElzgXrIdqF3J2lZ1w5pl9PcniENBJXL7EewUTNJ5sCRXYrghPg)

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcjNCkBAEADg@zzFptRMOFBcBk8ipdVopwzJTZ59/XzHzxeL9zEKGl3WIVpR0mjUG99RGdYpGBJc4F6yHahdydpWdcOaZfT3J4hDQSVy@xHsFEzSebAkV2K4IT4)

Comment: @MDXF Nice! I knew there was a way to determine with simple arithmetic just couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
q]2{P
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=q%5D2%7BP&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A4%0A16%0A128%0A10%0A12&debug=0)**

Alternative:

```
q2s{P
```

## Explanation

```
q]2{P  ~ Full program with implicit input (Q) at the end.

    P  ~ Prime factors.
   {   ~ Deduplicated.
q      ~ Equals?
 ]2    ~ The literal [2].
       ~ Output (implicitly).
```

Comment: `!-PQ2` is 5 bytes too, similar idea

Comment: `q2eP` for 4 bytes. `P` gives an ordered list, so `eP` is the largest prime factor.

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 4 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)!

```
Yf2=
```

**[Try it here.](https://matl.suever.net/?code=Yf2%3D&inputs=2&version=20.4.1)**

Returns `1` (or an array of several `1`s) for truthy and `0` or   (the empty string) for falsy.

## How?

```
Yf2=   % Full program.

Yf     % Prime factors.
  2=   % All equal 2?
       % Output implicitly.
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, thanks a lot!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks, addressed.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

-3 thanks to Deadcode

```js
f=
n=>!(n&n-2)

// test numbers 0-16
const tests = [f(0), false, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true]
const results = tests.map((res, n) => res === f(n))
document.write(
  results.every(res => res)
    ? "All tests passed "
    : [
        "Tests failed ",
        ...results.map((res, n) => !res && `f(${n}): expected ${tests[n]}`).filter(Boolean),
      ].join("<br />")
)
```

```css
body{font-size:3rem;font-family:monospace}
```

Explanation - this uses [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1053594/1903116) for checking if `n` is a power of 2, but uses `n&n-2` instead of `n&n-1` to make 1 return false

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! And, 8 bytes: `n=>n&n-2`. But by my interpretation OP specified that swapping truthy/falsey is not allowed, so, 11 bytes: `n=>!(n&n-2)`

Comment: Also I would recommend putting `f(0)` (or `!f(0)`, if you stick with the swap) as the first element of your test array. It's disingenuous to verify that your function is returning the wrong value for zero as part of the test suite, as by the challenge's rules, it can return either truthy or falsey for an input of zero.

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to skip the `n==1` check but didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: Another way you could save bytes, but stick with the same bitwise operation, is `n=>n<2|n&n-1`. This would also make it return the correct value for zero. There are two savings being done with that: using `n<2` instead of `n==1`, and using `|` bitwise OR instead of `||` logical OR (they both work with JavaScript's operator precedence).

Comment: Huh, didn't know bitwise OR worked like that. I think I'll stick with your previous version though.

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (Java / Perl / PCRE / .NET), 12 bytes

`^(\1\1|^x)*x$` - **13 bytes** - Powers of 2
`(\1\1|^x)+x$` - **12 bytes** - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Java | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9swDHzvr@CMDZHSRHXWt6nGsA0bMGDthvYxTQHFlhOlMu1JcuO062/PKMf7KBC/0CRPR92JG/Wgppvifm@qpnYBNpQLU4uxhP8rbTD2aM3ple6oc9K0S2tyyK3yHi6VQXiCoeaDChQealNARR12E5zBFSi38vMFh7B29dbD5y7XTTA1nTwB@GKshjJDve1/WSLyutCC@gmXH9uy1E4X11oV2sGyh70ssj8nh7TkXA5z/STI7TryM@azJWlQxTeDmnH@KsPWWm5K5oX@2SrrWXI2Ho8Tzp9eQg8MjIWjBE/EEP4yEMEZMSwJdy/9aTa6xVGMQT4fas8/VAjaIbhs@CO1VRMHeC7JjWVdW60QHrOSGLWEm1whknSDTRsgg6h2qLGbnQ@6Ega5hEFnDxNr5a90F@iavcUAgyGW7k4cBxASYpA49OcLsNSOKOEbawJLpvQIhA@AKXW@YqA1cKJRzmtKmJ2nCz4BnB1tCqtxFdYXb@E9RCS8ozBbEGO@Vm6@6AY9fYazhYQPzqmdF6WxlnWTUTfqTQEoaxe10TUyTCXgRYYzCqenJPBShXxNDlXE5kR1yFi/uUgL/onIDxsjtk41bBiR183ue3mtcKVpUjpBzqPSElhF47Eg7@LbPvLB5Joc2zoTNIuPyuVjFlwb3@dfuyEPQ8mSNz4hS7h8jt9J3Kr9Hbud3c5@3XV83L3exzXZp9Pz8zRNfwM) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbbtswDH3PV3DGhki5qE6fhqnGsA0bMGDdhvYxzQDFlhO1Mu1JcuO067dnlONdCsQvNMmjQ50j3qp7Nb8t7g6mamoX4JZyYWoxkfB/pQ3Gnqw5vdEddUZNu7Ymh9wq7@FSGYRHGGo@qEDhvjYFVNRh18EZ3IByG79ccQhbV@88fOxy3QRT08kRwCdjNZQZ6l3/yxKR14UW1E@4fN@WpXa6uNKq0A7WPex5kf05OaQl53KY62dB7raRnzGfrUmDKr4Y1IzzFxm21nJTMi/0z1ZZz5KzyWSScP74HHpkYCycJHgkhvCXgQjOiGFNuDvpp9n4BscxBvl0rD19VyFoh@Cy4Y/UVk0c4LkkN9Z1bbVCeMhKYtQSrnOFSNINNm2ADKLaocau9z7oShjkEgadPUxslf@qu0DX7C0GGAyxdHfiOIKQEIPEob9cgaV2RAnfWBNYMqdHIHwATKnzGQOtgRONcl5TwuwyXfEZ4OJkU1iNm7C9OIe3EJHwhsJiRYz5Vrnlqhv09BkuVhLeOaf2XpTGWtbNxt24NwWgrF3URtfIMJWAFxkuKEynJPBShXxLDlXE5kR1zFi/uUgL/oHIjxsjdk41bBiR183@W3mlcKNpUjpDzqPSElhF47Eg7@LbPvDB5Joc2zkTNIuPyuVDFlwb3@dfuyEPQ8mSVz4hS7h8it8obtWB3SxuFr9@dHzavTzELTmk89fnafob) |
| Perl | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NasMwEIRfZQlLrG1sLKX0UlmpA@m1p97qRCQhBoGauJILLqr66q7iBnpZdmZ/5utOzj6M71@ATkKwl@PeApYySVVt1q/rVYT24hh6xWW1khTAtElR6Jw59zBrzjMZobbKd9b0LCuy3H8efJ9OdF6IXNDp47r09O/y5NMjapLXXz4l7l1tqyWF2r6JrUqVb@Ut19wkmkpN49QtFhRMC4xlQwYDpCUiUD9QoispoJ/PJ7iJLYEL@ceKRsYYtX5@2Wg97lgjGvG9G@huwHHkhbhfcs5/AQ) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fS8MwFMW/ymVc1lza0mQgiGlmB/PVJ9/sDHOsEMi2mlSoxPjVa1YHvlzuOffP@fVHZ@@m0xegkxDs5bC3gJVMUtXbzctmHaG7OIZecVmvJQUwXVIUemfOAyza80JGaKzyvTUDy8qs8J/vfkgnuihFIej4cV16/Hd58ukBNcnrL58S966x9YpCY1/FTqXKd/KWa24STa3mcerynILpgLFszGCEtEQE6gcqdBUF9MvlDDezJXAh/1jRyBij1k/PW60n1opWfL@NlI84Tby8X3H@Cw) |
| PCRE | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH33V4QQaKKptuo2JBZftoEw9rDtzWqoXWrDYhrSCAW3397dyp72kMv9OufcHFe7fr1xtUPEowzhGUZT5Lw6Sa@cKUpFo9l0vJGyLkyQZXN22iif05yJ/G3WRhxF8CpoypMaFmxQNrRUyufty5OUjKOUASUQi5G2WrYqUOxKr6bHovwKHoI0@qwD5ggv56vl6v5hvrrDTIyqxlOis0QQk1XA3tL3j8ftKxPsinRFidm1wRtlIWNxus8ynFvMYLm9HGECbZ7wOGUDXnXONJ@K4hhzWBeAL5uLDQN2PQfQDgggJnsxQuimbP9qYtfZbQ7ZZMJAGtGbQ@cilDUlnoPYYJcqAo26iBPLGEPX4UTNVFk3w10CwVdSgYYaESt@QObnn62Uif5A8zRPvw8dG3ek75M4XSySJPkF) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLasMwELznK4QQWGrkxDbpIygml7YQKD20vcWpcFw5FlVkIStgSPPt7jr01IOWfc3MalzjhtXaNQ4Rj3KE5xjNkPPqIL1ypqwUjeazm7WUTWmCrNqj00b5ghZMFG/zLuIogldDUx7UuGCDsqGjUj5vXp6kZBylDCiBWEy01bJTgWJXeTXbl9V38BCk0UcdMEd4kS0Xy7v7bHmLmZjUradE54kgJq@BvaPvH4@bVybYGemaErPtgjfKQsbidJfnuLCYwXJ32sME2jzhccpGvOqdab8UxTHmsC4AX7UnG0bsKgPQFgggJjsxQeiqbP9qYlf5dQ7ZdMpAGtGrQ8cyVA0lnoPYaJcqA436iBPLGEPn8UTNVNW0410CwVdSgcYaESsuIHP5ZytlYqBFWqQ/nz2b9mQYkvghS5Jf) |
| .NET | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9Ra4MwFIX/SpALJnUpcX1rCBT23F9gLYi7nYH0RmKKUpvf7nRj7PE7HD7O6f2IYejQuQWCqQJ@4VQfj4QjP@XLlV/KS/m6TmI3wZKf3rIPf@@tw89MaHgapW8@YNN2HByzxMBS/4hihsaAk0PvbMxkpu2NQ7Nv/YOidJG9b4XCQFOpOq0CDmQqS7H@STSQdPjH5cZFIebNEfbnJrYdDjyf8h2Q@I2fYh6DjSg7P8S0zir1PzNJfn3jLCEDSiktSh4OSqlv) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RaoQwFER/JcgFk9oscZ/KhsBCn/sFroVg79ZA9kZiFmVtvt1qS@njGYbDzBAmjGOP3q8QTRPxE@f2dCKc@Llc@aW@1F/vs6hmWMvzc/EaboPz@FEIDQ@j9DVEtF3PwTNHDBwN9yQWsAa8HAfvUiEL7a4c7KELd0rSJ3bcC5UB26g2bwIOZBpHqf1JNJD0@Mf1zlUllt0RD282dT2OvJzLJyDxGz/EMkWXUPZhTHmbVet/ZpLCdsY7QgaUc16VfDkq9Q0) |

Subtracts increasing powers of 2 from \$tail\$, starting with \$1\$. As such, the sum of the subtracted powers will be \$2^a-1\$ where \$a\$ is the number of iterations so far. Once the loop has matched as many iterations as it can, asserts that the remaining \$tail=1\$.

Unlike the ECMAScript regexes, this needs to do no backtracking, thus is orders of magnitude faster in standard regex engines.

As with the 17 byte ECMAScript regex, it is quite suitable for solving this challenge, as the only change necessary is upping the minimum iteration count of the loop from `0` to `1` by changing the `*` quantifier to a `+`, at a cost of 0 bytes. But an added bonus here is that the first iteration of the loop can only match at the beginning of the string, so we can remove the first `^` anchor to save 1 byte. This does make the regex much slower in most regex engines though.

## Regex (<sub><sup>Java / Perl / PCRE / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex)</sup> / Ruby / .NET</sup></sub>), 22 bytes

`^((?=(\3\3|^x))(\2))*x$` - **23 bytes** - Powers of 2
`((?=(\3\3|^x))(\2))+x$` - **22 bytes** - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub> | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BasMwEEX3PsUguphJbSPFi4Ad0YPYDoRWSVSUsRmp1IHe3Y1cuhvm8R5/fqTbxM3q7/MkCeIjluKubik/48QdiBWl1HpCfLM4NEPzc1qIcNgT7ZaX9cl601Zm7MBbXVwmgQCec6aO6cNzW0CwoY5z8AlVpagAf4HgGAMd9y2E3ow29HosIMucZTnz1aHnhBlQ@XeZkV4NPXs5sE2sozvL@w2lBLWoHW8wU9/CLNmi7WFN9z9o@kr1t/jkMCZBJlp1ZQ5a618) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7RSsQwEEXf@xVD8GHGbUuy9ak1@CFthUWzu5E4KZOIXfDf66bi2zCHc7jLLV8jd5v/XKJkSLdUi7u4tf5IkQcQK0qpDfHF4tRN3c/rSoTTkeiwPmx3NJq@MfMA3urqHAUCeC6VNuV3z30FwYY2LcFnVI2iCvwZgmMM9HzsIYxmtmHUcwVF5iLLiS8OPWcsgOq/y8x0MHTvlcC@sE3uJG9XlBrUqh55h4X6HhYpFu0Pa4b/QfErt9/is8OUBZlo082T0foX) |
| Ruby | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Bi8IwEIXv/oqxCCZCh7QePMQggl49yN5aDYqxBsJY0ohdWPzr3UR2PczAvHnfm/GP8/fgQcHeNKZvkcwTNuuvNXpzukiwSkh43qwz4FRjQjcCsFdwVV4clMpqymRcuEog5uVBgqFLdEQFu9bZwKb5lP8h6Aw14cb4soxMFfmIfZDr3QOBJUgihru2rBAcMRk/Y/S9s1jWZzPioF7gZRLsOP3ZPkL3zkt/F3H2lgLQ/4nUU2m93W20Ho6MrRSr5/X859hzzuqS81k/GQaRFwshxC8) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Bi8IwEIXv/oqxCCa7dEjrRciGRdCrB9lb6wbFWANhLGnECuJfr4nsepiBefO@N@Mv@9vgQcHGNKZvkcwVloufBXqzO0iwSki4nqwz4FRjQjcCsEdwVV5slcpqymRcuEog5uVWgqFDdEQFu9bZwKb5lP8h6Aw14cT4VxmZKvIReyPHswcCS5BEDGdtWSE4YjK@x@h7ZbGszz6Ig3qAl0mw4/RnewndKy/9XcTZWwpA/ydST6X1ar3UemDsW7F6Vs/uvz3nrC45/@wnwyDyeSnEEw) |

This is a direct port of the 13 byte / 12 byte regex. Ruby, and Python's `regex` module, do not support nested backreferences, so they must be emulated via forward-declared backreferences. (Python's `re` module doesn't even support the latter.) The 13 byte version of this is faster than the 17 byte regexes, but golf-wise, they win.

Although this results in a fast regex that's compatible with six different engines, the [recursive solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259835/17216) provide the best golf for Python's `regex` module and Ruby.

#### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 18 bytes

```
.+
$*
(\1\1|^.)+.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcg5CoAwAEXB/p0jQjQQ/FlcTuAlgmhhYWMhlt49OuXcx3Nee23sslXvMB22qOhdfeu8qbVHBCKJzMDIxIz@FAooooQyGj4)

Takes its input in decimal. Uses the Java/Perl/PCRE/.NET pure regex.

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

```
say 1x<>~~/(\1\1|^.)+.$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7NasMwGHuVb8YQm/w0GesOjROyS0YPu@ywS9sNE5zF4NjGDrSjS497gD3iHmRpaBm7CAkJSVY4tZy0gT13Wup3D4E4WOFkL/TA1Wrle@6Gng9NF@RgrNCkjlC5RjSHfSeVIKykx6Yzvc0rVXir5ECCOIjw25yQLfENV9xVit3SY6U22a6YMd2N0BpHsLyqHEtWXNyZhSE9ev4BNWA5jtAo4wWp6f86u6xXD8@PLwVao78jN8K0hFK4viFYFawu56B1Ug@AVYTg5@sbUD7N7XhzYOXptCDbbJt9viY0TPBiGqc0vr/7NXaQRvspflomaZaeAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (PCRE1), 11 bytes

`^(x(?1)?x|x)$` - **13 bytes** - Powers of 2
`^(x(?1)?x)$` - **11 bytes** - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PCRE1 | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPbbtpAEH3nKya0CetgIrtIVWXjRGlK1QeaVIhIrQi1XLOGVc3aWq8LSeDXS2d37cS5SLX8sJczZ86cmY3zvLeI4/0bxuO0nFMY5LGgJ8vTVryMBIT5dAYBjNsf1@vfv/rlj9vb75Pl@/WS7H@SDTlzrbPNdmO93VvPAW0bjvMgzLuu33okL@ScZYq9eSQYXzw9Yxme0mj1EnfaYlxCjksZUiEyQeKMFxK02uMVLYpoQa17zON5MQJgMIDqVC31OeXz1AdBZSk4uP5OU64ixokF9y3AL59itpRykls9dxY4PpSI6b8LJWRqpwIWuNBgzWnU4UVeSh@Uh3AsqA9NdSgnl8JEC1qUqTRrVUeSFFTakJUS0y7k0txkf2gsMzHtz0wqZA00eRhnq5yllOQ2fLsYD8NPV5Pz0Qi2Znc9@fzBhiOT0CzqDI5lqFgC5EBQq/Yh0Z4mBKtBtA1tRaSlCYhQiQ6Hw7kHh8UNx@42OE2eijjBAKLE3ymntDkLKlPGKTFdYdw2Plk@Ytzacy0Kw7iDNUYyY0SDTuIQvSWWZQN3bcizAq/NTcL4nHR6nSqx@rirDELMQdDsi@dxdXj2Ci90Nb4LKMTD5I9cpmkqHadrs5tyt@vOfJyoFRZOChs6m44ShqUUeDkLGvEPRrCAq5kZBNz1odtlzYpNV9Us1J2lGxoTQW24vB6NbMAcDLum/2ocbOg3Sq6bWbGcBuDAdluTog96Iobj8dU4vLz6ej65@PJcQE1xZwE6oyolnRveMf3xX0BNG3FU1Yti/qtUVfoBijk6@o@YJ3xtD4Zq6NpPeXevO9aw2yB2LT2ynhlFQSkqsR4ee/XqWru903Ndx/kbJ2m0KPa9VFn/Dw) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNtb5swEP6eX3HN1sY0pIJFmiYIrbqu0z5k7RSl0qY0Q4wYYo0YZMySvuSvLzvb0NIXaYgP9r0899xz57goBmkc794wHmfVgsKoiAU9Wh534mUkICxmcwhg0v24Xv/@Nax@3Nx8ny7fr5dk95NsyIlrnWystzvrubtrw2ERhEXf9TuP0KVcsFxht02C8fSpjeVopdHqZdxxh3EJBR5lSIXIBYlzXkrQXA9XtCyjlFp3WMfzYgyA0QhqqzpqO@WLzAdBZSU4uP5WQ64ixokFdx3Ar5hhtYxyUlgDdx44PlQYM3wXSsjVTSWkeNDBGtOwQ0dRSR@UgnAoqA9tdkinkMJkC1pWmTRn1UeSlFTakFcSy6ZyaTz5HxrLXMyGc1MKUQMNHsb5qmAZJYUN384m5@Gny@npeAz35nY1/fzBhgNT0ByaCo5loFgCZE9Qq9Eh0ZomBLvBaBu6CkhTExAhE50O@wsP9strjtNtYZo6NXCCCUSRv1VKaXFSKjPGKTFTYdw2Olk@xriN5poUpnEHe4xkzogOOopD1JZYlg3ctaHIS3QbT8L4gvQGvbqw@rirBMKYvaA9F8/jynjyCi70dXwfkIiHxR@xzNBUOU7X5jbjbt@d@7hRK2yclDb0Nj1FDFsp0TkPWvkPQrCAq50ZBdz1od9n7Y7NVNUuNJOlGxoTQW24uBqPbcAaDKem/3odbBi2Wm6GWaMcB@DA/X0DijrojTifTC4n4cXl19Pp2ZfnBBqIWwtQGdUp6V3znpmP/yLUjBFXVb0o5r8KVZcfIZmDg/@QeYLX9eBcLV33Ke72dcVacpuIbUevrGdWUVCKTKyHx16/us525wxc13H@xkkWpeVukCnp/wE) |

I'm not sure when this recursive regex was originally discovered. It was likely an accidental discovery, when someone tried to match palindromes and found that due to PCRE1's atomic subroutine calls, words consisting of only one distinct letter would only match when their length was a power of 2.

Explaining why this works is complicated, but I do intend to do it sometime.

This regex is absolutely phenomenal at being ported to this challenge; it loses 2 bytes in doing so.

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl / PCRE</sup></sub>), 15 bytes

`^x(x(?1)?+x|x|)$` - **16 bytes** - Powers of 2
`^x(x(?1)?+x|x)$` - **15 bytes** - Completely even

This is a port of the PCRE1 regex to engines that may have non-atomic subroutine calls.

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Perl | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/ykWCzaUtTYS9LI2t4F598m1zwQ0LgUxrUiEjxq9eYyfs5XLPuX/Orz9Y8zL@/AKxAoI5fe8NkEokKev1artaRuhOlhInmaiXAgPoLikMvdXHAWYfx5mI0BrpeqMHmpVZ4S5fbkgnqih5wfFwfiw1/y5LPr4SheLxy6XEvW1NvcDQmne@k6mynXjm6qckupbTOHV5jkF3QGnmM/CQlhBB3qAitsJA3Hw@wU1sCZyLP1aiRYxRqbfNWqnx01NPG45N7q/@imQcWbngjN0B) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/ykWCzaUtTYS9mMZWcK8@7W1zwQ0Lgag16SAji1@9i1Xw5XLPuX/Orz9Y8zIef4FYAcGcv/cGSCWSlPVm/bZeRejOlhInmahXAgPoLikMvdWnAWYfp5mI0BrpeqMHmpVZ4X6@3JBOVFHyguPhcltqni5LPi6JQnH75VLi3ramXmBozTvfyVTZTjxy9UMSXctpnLo8x6A7oDTzGXhIS4ggr1ARW2Egbj6f4Ca2BM7FnZVoEWNU6nW7UWr89NTThmOT@z@PZBxZueCM/QM) |
| PCRE1 | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNdb9owFH3nV9yytThNqMiQpikhrbqOaQ@snRCVNlEWseAEa8GxHDNoC3997NombfohLcqDP@4959xzrxMh2lmS7N4wnuTLGYWeSCQ9mZ82kvlUQizGE4hg2Py4Wv3@1V3@uL39Ppq/X83J7uearMmZ75y5681647zdOc9jmh4ciygWrh82HvFLNWOFJqgfScazp2eswFM6XbyMO20wrkDgUsVUykKSpOClAiP4eEHLcppR5x55giDBAOj1YH@ql@ac8lkegqRqKTn44dZALqaMEwfuG4CfGCNbTjkRTtufRJ0QlhjTfRcrKPROJ2S4MMEG06rDC7FUIWgb4VjSEOrqUI5Q0mZLWi5zZde6jjQtqfKgWCqkzdTc3hR/aKIKOe5OLBWiRgY8ToqFYDklwoNvF8N@/OlqdD4YwMburkefP3hwZAntomLoOBaKpUAOJHUqH1LjaUqwGoz2oKmBjDQJU1Ri0uFwFsBhecOxuzVMy7MHTjGBaPF32iljTkZVzjgltiuMe9YnJ8QYv/LciMI03sEap6pgxASdJDF6SxzHA@57IIoSr@1NyviMtNqtPbH@uK8NwpiDqN6XIOD68OwVXHBNvAsoJEDyRyzbNE3H6cruxtx3/UmIE7XAwknpQWvd0sKwlBIvJ1Et/8EIFnE9M72I@yG4LqtXbLuqZ6HqLF3ThEjqweX1YOABcjDsmvn34@BBt1Zy1cw9ymkEHdhsKlD0wUxEfzi8GsaXV1/PRxdfnguoIO4cQGd0paR1w1u2P@GLUNtGHFX9olj4KtSevodijo7@I@YJXjOAvh665lPc7euO1ey2EduGGdnAjqKkFJU4D499/@oa212n7fudzt8kzadZuWvn2vp/) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNdb9owFH3nV9yytThNqMiQpikhrbqOaQ@snRCVNlEWseAEa8GxHDNoC3997NombfohLcqDP84999xzrxMh2lmS7N4wnuTLGYWeSCQ9mZ82kvlUQizGE4hg2Py4Wv3@1V3@uL39Ppq/X83J7uearMmZ75y5683aebtznkOaHhyLKBauHzYe6Us1Y4Xmrx9JxrOnZ6zAUzpdvMSdNhhXIHCpYiplIUlS8FKB0Xu8oGU5zahzj3mCIEEA9HqwP9VLc075LA9BUrWUHPxwaygXU8aJA/cNwE@MMVtOORFO259EnRCWiOm@ixUUeqcDMlwYsOG06vBCLFUI2kU4ljSEujqUI5S00ZKWy1zZta4jTUuqPCiWCtNmam5vij80UYUcdyc2FbJGhjxOioVgOSXCg28Xw3786Wp0PhjAxu6uR58/eHBkE9pFlaHjWCqWAjmQ1Kl8SI2nKcFqEO1BUxMZaRKmqMSEw@EsgMPyhmN3a5w2z544xQCixd9pp4w5GVU545TYrjDuWZ@cEDF@5bkRhWG8gzVOVcGIAZ0kMXpLHMcD7nsgihKv7U3K@Iy02q19Yv1xXxuEmIOo3pcg4Prw7BVecA3eBRQSYPJHLts0nY7Tld2Nue/6kxAnaoGFk9KD1rqlhWEpJV5Oolr8gxEs4npmehH3Q3BdVq/YdlXPQtVZuqYJkdSDy@vBwAPMwbBr5t@PgwfdWslVM/cspxF0YLOpSNEHMxH94fBqGF9efT0fXXx5LqCiuHMAndGVktYNb9n@hC@gto04qvpFsfBVqn36Hoo5OvqPmCd8zQD6euiaT3m3rztWs9sitg0zsoEdRUkpKnEeHvv@1TW2u07b9zudv0maT7Ny18619f8A) |
| PCRE2 | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH33V4QQaO5stS1uQ2LpyzYQxh62vVkXapfasJqGNEJB/e3uVva0h1zu1znn5tjGXle5bSxhjmSEzimZEevUXjpl27JSPJjP7nIpm7L1suoOVrfKFbwAUbzP@yAkAb4am3KvxgXjlfE9l/Jl/fosJYQkAaREYjHRRsteeU5t5dRsV1Y/3mGQrT5oT0NCF@lysXx4TJf3FMSk7hxnOosFa7Ma2Xv@8fm0fgMBJ6JrztpN712rDGYQJdsso4WhgMv9cYcTbIdxGCUw4tVg2@5bcRrRENcF4qvuaPyIXaUI2iABxngrJoTclM1fzcwqu80xm04BpQm/OXQofdVw5kIUG@1SpefBEITMAAA5jSdqUFXTjXcJgl9JBBlrwoy4oMzln60cxPVr4APPE8inw3k4A7te4yhN4vgX) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdS8MwFH3frwgh0FzXbm2ZyshKX1QYiA/q2zpDV9M12KUhzaAw/e31dvjkQy7365xzc2xjx01uG0uYIxmhS0oWxDp1lE7ZtqwUD5aLm1zKpmy9rLqT1a1yBS9AFK/LPghJgK/GpjyqacF4ZXzPpXzaPj9KCSFJACmRWMy00bJXnlNbObU4lNWXdxhkq0/a05DQVbpere/u0/UtBTGrO8eZzmLB2qxG9p6/vT9sX0DAheias3bXe9cqgxlEyT7LaGEo4HJ/PuAE22EcRglMeDXYtvtUnEY0xHWB@Ko7Gz9hNymCdkiAMd6LGSFXZfNXM7PJrnPM5nNAacKvDp1KXzWcuRDFJrtU6XkwBCEzAEAu04kaVNV0012C4FcSQaaaMCN@UObnn60cxPgx8IHnCeTz4XsANo5xlCZx/As) |

## Regex (<sub><sup>PCRE</sup></sub> / Ruby), 16 bytes

`^x(x\g<1>?+x|x|)$` - **17 bytes** - Powers of 2
`^x(x\g<1>?+x|x)$` - **16 bytes** - Completely even

This is a port of the PCRE1 recursive regex to Ruby's subroutine call syntax.

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PCRE1 | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNdb9owFH3nV9yytTglVGRI05QQqq7rtAfWTohKmyiLWHCCteBYjjNoC3997NombfohLcqDP@4959xzr2MhOmkc794wHmflnEJfxJKeLAaNeDGTEInJFEIYNT@uVr9/9coft7ffx4v3qwXZ/VyT9U3a9wan7fVmvXHe7pznQU0XjkUYibYXNB4JCjVnuWaoH0nG06dnLMdTOlu@jBs0GFcgcKkiKmUuSZzzQoFRfLykRTFLqXOPPL4fYwD0@7A/1UtzTvk8C0BSVUoOXrA1kMsZ48SB@wbgJybIllFOhNPxpmE3gBJjeu8iBbne6YQUFybYYFp1eCFKFYD2EY4lDaCuDuUIJW22pEWZKbvWdSRJQZULeamQNlULe5P/obHK5aQ3tVSIGhrwKM6XgmWUCBe@nY8uok9X47PhEDZ2dz3@/MGFI0toFxVD17FQLAFyIKlT@ZAYTxOC1WC0C00NZKRJmKESkw6Hcx8OixuO3a1hWp49cIIJRIu/004Zc1KqMsYpsV1h3LU@OQHGeJXnRhSm8S7WOFM5IyboJI7QW@I4LnDPBZEXeG1vEsbnpNVp7Yn1xz1tEMYchPW@@D7Xh6ev4ELbxLcBhfhI/ohlm6bpOF3Z3YR7bW8a4EQtsXBSuNBat7QwLKXAy2lYy38wgoVcz0w/5F4A7TarV2y7qmeh6ixd05hI6sLl9XDoAnIw7Jr59@PgQq9WctXMPcoghC5sNhUo@mAm4mI0uhpFl1dfz8bnX54LqCDuHEBndKWkdcNbtj/Bi1DbRhxV/aJY8CrUnr6PYo6O/iPmCV7Thws9dM2nuNvXHavZbSO2DTOyvh1FSSkqcR4e@/7VNba7bsfzut2/cZLN0mLXybT1/wA) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNdb9owFH3nV9yytTglVGRI05QQqq7rtAfWTohKmyiLWHCCteBYjjNoC3997NombfohLcqDP@4959xzr2MhOmkc794wHmflnEJfxJKeLAaNeDGTEInJFEIYNT@uVr9/9coft7ffx4v3qwXZ/VyT9U3a9wan7fVm7bzdOc9jmi4cizASbS9oPOIXas5yTVA/koynT89Yjqd0tnwZN2gwrkDgUkVUylySOOeFAiP4eEmLYpZS5x55fD/GAOj3YX@ql@ac8nkWgKSqlBy8YGsglzPGiQP3DcBPTJAto5wIp@NNw24AJcb03kUKcr3TCSkuTLDBtOrwQpQqAG0jHEsaQF0dyhFK2mxJizJTdq3rSJKCKhfyUiFtqhb2Jv9DY5XLSW9qqRA1NOBRnC8FyygRLnw7H11En67GZ8MhbOzuevz5gwtHltAuKoauY6FYAuRAUqfyITGeJgSrwWgXmhrISJMwQyUmHQ7nPhwWNxy7W8O0PHvgBBOIFn@nnTLmpFRljFNiu8K4a31yAozxKs@NKEzjXaxxpnJGTNBJHKG3xHFc4J4LIi/w2t4kjM9Jq9PaE@uPe9ogjDkI633xfa4PT1/BhbaJbwMK8ZH8Ecs2TdNxurK7Cffa3jTAiVpi4aRwobVuaWFYSoGX07CW/2AEC7memX7IvQDabVav2HZVz0LVWbqmMZHUhcvr4dAF5GDYNfPvx8GFXq3kqpl7lEEIXdhsKlD0wUzExWh0NYour76ejc@/PBdQQdw5gM7oSknrhrdsf4IXobaNOKr6RbHgVag9fR/FHB39R8wTvKYPF3romk9xt687VrPbRmwbZmR9O4qSUlTiPDz2/atrbHfdjud1u3/jJJulxa6Taev/AQ) |
| PCRE2 | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdS8MwFH3frwgh0MSlW1umMrK6FxUG4oP6ts7Q1XQNZmlIMyi4/fZ6O3zyIZf7dc65Oa5xw2rtGoeIRznCc4xmyHl1kF45U1aKRvPZzVrKpjRBVu3RaaN8QQsmird5F3EUwauhKQ9qXLBB2dBRKZ83L09SMo5SBpRALCbaatmpQLGrvJrty@o7eAjS6KMOmCO8yJaL5d19trzFTEzq1lOi80QQk9fA3tH3j8fNKxPsB@maErPtgjfKQsbidJfnuLCYwXJ32sME2jzhccpGvOqdab8UxTHmsC4AX7UnG0bsKgPQFgggJjsxQeiqbP9qYlf5dQ7ZdMpAGtGrQ8cyVA0lnoPYaJcqA436iBPLGEM/44maqappx7sEgq@kAo01IlZcQObyz1bKxPDZ0744rNKH9bQ/92dGhiGJszRJfgE) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdS8MwFH3frwgh0MSlW1umMrK6FxUG4oP6ts7Q1XQNZmlIMyjM/fZ6O3zyIZf7dc65Oa5xw2rtGoeIRznCc4xmyHl1kF45U1aKRvPZzVrKpjRBVu3RaaN8QQsmird5F3EUwauhKQ9qXLBB2dBRKZ83L09SMo5SBpRALCbaatmpQLGrvJrty@o7eAjS6KMOmCO8yJaL5d19trzFTEzq1lOi80QQk9fA3tH3j8fNKxPsjHRNidl2wRtlIWNxustzXFjMYLk77WECbZ7wOGUjXvXOtF@K4hhzWBeAr9qTDSN2lQFoCwQQk52YIHRVtn81sav8OodsOmUgjejVoWMZqoYSz0FstEuVgUZ9xIlljKHzeKJmqmra8S6B4CupQGONiBUXkLn8s5UyMXz2tC8Oq/RhPe1/ekaGIYmzNEl@AQ) |
| **Ruby** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BawIxEIXv/RXTpWBi2SHZa4wi2GsPxdtqg2JcA2FcshFTEP/6NpHWwwzMm/e9mXDZ/4wBNHzZzqYeyV5htVwvMdjdQYHTQsH15LwFrzsbhxcAdwTf1nKrdbWhSuWFbwVi3WwVWDpkR1Zw6L2LbFJP@B@C3lIXT4zPmsy0mc/YEzmeAxA4giJiPBvHpOCIxfgcs@@RxapUTYmDvkNQRXCv5c/@EodHXvlb5jk4ikD/J0ovZczH58qY8TuxtOlmcr54T7d042/jKGrZCPEL)** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BawIxEIXv/opxKZi07JDsNaZFsNceirfVBsW4BsK4ZCOmUPzrayLWwwzMm/e9mXDe/Y4BNHzbzqYeyV5guVgtMNjtXoHTQsHl6LwFrzsbhwmAO4Bva7nRulpTpfLCtwKxbjYKLO2zIys49N5FNqtn/IGgt9TFI@PzJjNt5jP2RA6nAASOoIgYT8YxKThiMT7H7LtnsSpVr8RBXyGoIrhp@bM/x@GeV/6WeQ6OItD/idJLGfP5tTRm/Eksrbu5fP94S3@Jv4yjqGUjxA0)** |

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl / PCRE2 /</sup></sub> Boost / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex)</sup>), 15 bytes

`^x(x((?1))\2|)$` - Powers of 2
`^x(x((?1)?)\2)$` - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Perl | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/ykWCzcWWJoW9LI1WcK8@@TZdcMNCINMu6aAjxq/eXTthL5d7zv1zft3Ju6fx8weYVxDd5ePogJWKpK436916maC9eM6CFqpeKoxgW1IYO2/PPcz255lK0DgdOmd7nhVZHr7fQ08nJi9kLvH0dV9a/buCfHxmBtX9V6DEo29cXWFs3Ks8aKrioB659iGZrfU0pm6xwGhb4DwbMhiAlhBB36BkvsTIwnw@wU1sBC7VHyuzKqVkzMt2Y8z4NvCB85VE3FdXZOMoikoK8Qs) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7NasMwEIRfZQlLrCU2lgy9RFbsQHrtqbcmFWmJQaAkjuSCi1Bf3VXcQC/LzuzPfP3J2afp/A3oJAR7/TxawFImqerd9nW7idBdHUOvuKw3kgKYLikKvTOXARb7y0JGaK3yvTUDy4os918ffkgnOi9ELuh0uy81/y5PPq1Rk7z/8inx6FpbVxRa@yYOKlV@kI9c85BoajWPU7daUTAdMJaNGYyQlohA/UCJrqSAfrmc4Wa2BC7kHysaGWPU@vllp/X0PrKRsUZQQ/uKcJp4UQnOfwE) |
| PCRE2 | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdS8MwFH3frwgh0FyXbm2ZysjKXlQYiA/q2zpDV9M12KUhzWAw/e31dvjkQy7365xzc1zjhtXaNY4wT3JC55TMiPP6oLx2bVlpHs1nN2ulmrINquqOzrTaF7wAWbzO@0iQCF@NTXXQ44IN2oaeK/W0eX5UCgRJASmRWE6MNarXgVNXeT3bl9VX8BhUa44mUEHoIlsulnf32fKWgpzUnefM5IlkbV4je8/f3h82LyDhQkzNWbvtg2@1xQzidJfntLAUcLk/7XGCbZGIOIURr8@u7T41pzEVuC4RX3UnG0bsKkPQFgkwJjs5IeSqbP9qZlf5dY7ZdAooTfjVoWMZqoYzL1BstEuXgUfnSDALAOQynmhAV0033iUJfiWVZKwJs/IHZX7@2cpBDh9nfuZ8nQIU2TewYUjiLE2SXw) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDNa4MwFL/3rwhBMG@NrUq3UVLxsg0KY4dtt9oF62KVpTHEFITSv909y0475PG@fh95trHjJreNJYEjGaFLShbEOnWUTlldVoqFy8VdLmVTai@r7mRbrVzBChDF@7IPOQnx1diURzUtGK@M75mUL9vXZymBkwSQEonFrDWt7JVn1FZOLQ5l9eMdBqnbU@spJ3SVrlfrh8d0fU9BzOrOsaDNYhHorEb2nn18Pm3fQMCFtDUL9K73TiuDGUTJPstoYSjgcn8@4ATbPOZRAhNeDVZ334rRiHJcF4ivurPxE3aTImiHBBjjvZgRclM2f3VgNtltjtl8DihN2O1Cp9JXDQscR7HpXKr0LBxCHhgAIJfJYguqarrJlyD4lUSQqSaBEVeUuf47KwMxfg1sYCxPIIcCfY1jHKVJHP8C) |
| **Boost** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNtb5swEP6eX3HLpsYu0EIq7QOEVpq0PzDtw6Y0RdRxwFpiLGOUl61/vdnZNIxmxB/A9/bcPXdnplRQMHb8KCRbN0sOs@eqqs2t5gXf3ZRK3Y/OTXzHuDKikrdLkRcSVYJlQq4qvcmtuo1iZa4hU/MFpPBt/GW7/fV81/zc7398Lz9vS3J82pEdIQ8RpY/TP/TTkZ67jH24VmmmvCjplSAwneb55n4kpIFNLiSh8HsEeNQcTWsuiaJBtEjDBBr0uZtmBior2YDCXmqzjGP0FbJApWpM4uJZJWsDjmMcO/6gOYIlJ12N/FgJ2zJ/i0DKQCzsIQ19OPAOvOBmLSQnTmBC@m0empxqtccGyhDbk5tKEOdwwzKsi1Dqg4x8UFWN5tayEnJJJsGEJh2AjNBqfT6kfU5xLK3yYQAXPOfvQUQhxuT/sNy4rm06ybetNJeRFy0S2PBNzQ2pfZjsJrYw7EiNRtviLr5rhUil7fUslVECnif6jO0xen@mcb1YAel3Pqt5rllJSI8XvbJZA7Hw3Qh8nA6lA1gnvAMFpG6pkMmjxMbhmKJk0L2dU9UYmM1A/O/zMrosMbcU5N32dE8ErrjW9ALh4QLPirGfcQxfta70OBnG4RRWFsnB@BbAZk3sRnZ4qOnjje3/rdrhZ0wcxgXi7a39am4aLQGX4eUYBtE0DF/Zap0X9TFYuwyZG@lf)** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNtb5swEP6eX3HLpsYu0EIq7QOEVpq0PzDtw6Y0RdRxwFpiLGOUl61/vdnZNIxmxB/A9/bcPXdnplRQMHb8KCRbN0sOs@eqqs2t5gXf3ZRK3Y/OTXzHuDKikrdLkRcSVYJlQq4qvcmtuo1iZa4hU/MFpPBt/GW7/fV81/zc7398Lz9vS3J82pEdIQ8R/UMfp/TTkZ67jH24VmmmvCjplSAwneb55n4kpIFNLiSh8HsEeNQcTWsuiaJBtEjDBBr0uZtmBior2YDCXmqzjGP0FbJApWpM4uJZJWsDjmMcO/6gOYIlJ12N/FgJ2zJ/i0DKQCzsIQ19OPAOvOBmLSQnTmBC@m0empxqtccGyhDbk5tKEOdwwzKsi1Dqg4x8UFWN5tayEnJJJsGEJh2AjNBqfT6kfU5xLK3yYQAXPOfvQUQhxuT/sNy4rm06ybetNJeRFy0S2PBNzQ2pfZjsJrYw7EiNRtviLr5rhUil7fUslVECnif6jO0xen@mcb1YAel3Pqt5rllJSI8XvbJZA7Hw3Qh8nA6lA1gnvAMFpG6pkMmjxMbhmKJk0L2dU9UYmM1A/O/zMrosMbcU5N32dE8ErrjW9ALh4QLPirGfcQxfta70OBnG4RRWFsnB@BbAZk3sRnZ4qOnjje3/rdrhZ0wcxgXi7a39am4aLQGX4eUYBtE0DF/Zap0X9TFYuwyZG@lf)** |
| **Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEETv/opF5LDb2kZyb3ZFPsR1ICRKoqKuzEqlDvTfncilt2Eeb5j5nm@R31b/NUfJkO6pFnd1S/2ZIg8gVpRS62HBBXFviD66X9qtz240fWOmAbzV1SUKBPBc9Dbls@e@gmBDm@bgM6pGUQX@AsExBnrvegijmWwY9VRBkbnIcuSrQ88ZC6D6L5mJXg0998rAdq1N7iinG0oNalEvvMFCfQ@zFIu2wprh/1D8zu2P@OwwZUEmWnVjOq0f)** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEETv/opF5LDb2kZyb3ZFPsR1ICRKoqKuzEqhztc7kUtvwzzeMPMj3yJ/rP5njpIhPVIt7uqW@jtFHkCsKKXWw4IL4t7Qnr462q2vbjR9Y6YBvNXVJQoE8Fz0NuWz576CYEOb5uAzqkZRBf4CwTEG@ux6CKOZbBj1VEGRuchy5KtDzxkLoPovmYneDb32ysB2rU3uKKcbSg1qUW@8wUJ9D7MUi7bCmuH/ULzn9ld8dpiyIBOtujGd1k8)** |

I discovered this recursive regex on 2022-07-18 while working on
[Sum of Powers of 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179174/sum-of-powers-of-2/250059#250059). It relies on subroutine calls being atomic.

```
^            # tail = N = input number
x            # tail -= 1
(            # Define subroutine (?1)
    x        # match += 1; tail -= 1
    ((?1))   # \2 = match made by recursive call; match += \2; tail -= \2
    \2       # match += \2; tail -= \2
|    # or
             # Match nothing, causing a cascading pop to the top level of
             # recursion, ending the match.
)
$            # Assert that we've reached the end of the string.
```

This is similar to `^(\1\1|^x)*x$`, in that the `(?1)` subroutine call will always return \$2^a-1\$ where \$a\$ is the depth of recursion it reached. This is why an extra \$1\$ is subtracted at the beginning (it could just as easily be done at the end, but that would be slightly slower due to backtracking).

It is very easily ported to solving this challenge; the first iteration at which it has a choice of whether to match nothing just has to be pushed down one level, at a cost of 0 bytes.

## Regex (<sub><sup>PCRE2</sup></sub> / Ruby), 16 bytes

`^x(x(\g<1>)\2|)$` - Powers of 2
`^x(x(\g<1>?)\2)$` - Completely even

| Regex engine | Powers of 2 | Completely even |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PCRE2 | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdS8MwFH3frwgh0FyXbm2ZykjrXlQYiA/q2zpDV9O12KUhzWAw99vr7fDJh1zu1znn5tjaDunK1pYwRzJC55TMiHV6r5y2bVFqHsxnNyul6qL1quwOtmm1y3kOMn@b94EgAb4Km2qvxwXjtfE9V@p5/fKkFAgSA1IisZw0plG99pza0unZrii/vcOg2ubQeCoIXSTLxfLuPlneUpCTqnOcNVkkWZtVyN7z94/H9StIOJOm4qzd9N612mAGYbzNMpobCrjcH3c4wbaIRBjDiNcn23ZfmtOQClyXiC@7o/EjNk0QtEECjNFWTgi5Kpu/mpk0u84xm04BpQm/OnQofFlz5gSKjXbpwvPgFAhmAICcxxMb0GXdjXdJgl@JJRlrwoy8oMzln60c5PB54iee79P4AfLkB9gwRGESR9Ev) | [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDNS8MwFL/vrwgh0MSlW1umMtK6iwoD8aDe1hm6mq7BLA1pBoXh315fhycPebyv30eea92Yb1zrEPGoQHiJ0QI5r47SK2eqWtFoubjZSNlWJsi6OzltlC9pyUT5tuwjjiJ4DTTlUU0LNigbeirl8/blSUrGUcqAEojFTFstexUodrVXi0NVfwcPQRp90gFzhFfZerW@u8/Wt5iJWdN5SnSRCGKKBth7@v7xuH1lgl2Qbigxuz54oyxkLE73RYFLixks9@cDTKDNEx6nbMKrwZnuS1EcYw7rAvB1d7ZhwuYZgHZAADHZixlCV2X7VxObF9c5ZPM5A2lErxc6VaFuKfEcxKZzqSrQaIg4sYwxdJksaqbqtpt8CQRfSQWaakSs@AGZn39npUyMnwMdaHnM04cNK8HYOCZxlibJLw) |
| **Ruby** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Bi8IwEIXv@ytmi2Cy0CHpNWZB0KsH2VvrBqWxBsJY0ogVZP96TcT1MAPz5n1vJlwOtymAhq3t7Ngj2Suslj9LDHbfKnBaKLienLfgdWfj8AHgjuDrUu60LhoqVFr4WiCW1U6BpTY5koJD711k83LOXwh6S108Mb6oElMnPmFv5HgOQOAIsojxbByTgiNm43tMvmcWK8biizjoPwgqC@4z/9lf4vDMy3/LNAdHEej/RO65jFlvVsZMvyMbWdMt5DdvqjufTZMoZSXEAw)** | **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Bi8IwEIXv/oqxCCZCh6TXmBVBrx5kb60bdjHWQBhLGrFe/OvdRNTDDMyb972ZcP27jwE07G1rhw7J3mCz/l5jsL9HBU4LBbez8xa8bm3sJwDuBL4u5UHroqFCpYWvBWJZHRRYOiZHUrDvvItsXs75C0FvqY1nxpdVYurEJ@yDnC4BCBxBFjFejGNScMRs/IzJ98xixVAsiIN@QFBZcNP8Z3eN/TMv/y3THBxFoPeJ3HMZs91tjBl/Bjawpl3KrxVvKj4bR1HKSoh/)** |

This is a port of the non-atomic recursive regex to Ruby's subroutine call syntax.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `-`, \$ 4 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 3.29 bytes

```
bdiP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSrlLsgqWlJWm6FkuSUjIDIEyoyIJFxkYQFgA)
or [verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_weJ0Q92lpSVpuhZLklIyAyDMBVBqsaGBAYQJAA)

Port of [Dennis's MATL answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142577/114446)

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `DD`, \$ 5 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.12 bytes

```
1-A^<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_WbSSi4tS7IKlpSVpuhZLDXUd42wgbKjQgkXGRhAWAA)
or [verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_UXTs4nQXl6WlJWm6FksNdR3jbCDsBVBqsaGBAYQJAA)

Port of [Dennis's Jelly answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142578/114446)

**Note**: a plain "power of two" answer would be 5 chars: [`b1c1=`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLkwyTDW0hbKgQTAoA) (is the count of 1s in the binary representation equal to 1?)

##### Explanation

```python
bdiP  # Implicit input
      # - flag decrements
b     # Convert to a binary string
 di   # Get the list of digits
      # This is a non-empty list of ones
      # if the input is a power of two
   P  # Push the product of this list
      # Implicit output
```

```python
1-A^<  # Implicit input
1-     # Subtract one
  A^   # Xor with input
       # The highest set bit will only be conserved
       # if the input is a power of two
    <  # Is more than input?
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `g`, 4 bytes

```
Kḣv₂
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBZyIsIiIsIkvhuKN24oKCIiwiIiwiMlxuNFxuMTZcbjEyOFxuMTBcbjEyXG4xNFxuMThcbjEiXQ==)

Can probably be golfed but it’s painful to do this on mobile.

Outputs `1` for truthy, `0` or the empty list for falsy.

```
K    # divisors of input
 ḣ   # without the first element
  v  # vectorize the following over it
   ₂ # is even?
     # (after which the `g` flag takes the minimum of the stack)
```

Comment: 2 bytes with `g` flag, ports MATL: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBZyIsIiIsIuKAuWIiLCIiLCIyXG40XG4xNlxuMTI4XG4xMFxuMTJcbjE0XG4xOFxuMSJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 40 bytes

```powershell
param($i)(($i-band(-$i))-eq$i)-and$i-ne0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVTUwNI6CYl5qVo6AJ5mrqphUBKF8gHCuelGvz//9/QyAIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `M`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
⁻ḃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kq9S7IKlpSVpuhbLHjXufrijeUlxUnIxVGjBImMjCAsA)

Port of [Dennis's MATL answer](/a/142577/114446): decrement, convert to binary, take minimum.

---

A plain "power of two" answer would be **4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md):**

```
2BSḅ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy4ycgh_uaF1SnJRcDBVasMjYCMICAA)

Convert to a binary list, sum equals one?

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 bytes

```
ᛃ
```

Doesn't work on TIO.

Comment: Fails for input `1`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Trying the program that produces the inverse output, `ᛄ` (which works on TIO), succeeds for input `1`.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
IntegerQ@Log2@#&&#>1&
```

Comment: @deleter I think it works for `1` now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ÆEL’¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm6vPo4aZh9b8///fBAA)

Comment: Kind of different approach :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 25 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`^(11+)\1$
$1
^11$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLOyFOw9BQWzPGUIVLxZArztBQ5f9/QzMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 5 bytes

```
;R♂╙c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9866NHMpkdTZyb//28BAA)

Explanation:

```
;R♂╙c
;      duplicate n
 R     range(1, n+1)
  ♂╙   powers of 2
    c  contains n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 24 bytes

```hs
f n=elem n$map(2^)[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY1JzVXIU8lN7FAwyhOM9pQTy8v9n9uYmaegq1CSj4XJ1DCV0EjpkJB106hoLQkuKTIJ09BRaE4I79coUJbW0nXTklbG8TTSFOo0NRUiDbQ0zM0MIj9DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 4 bytes

```
yN2=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/7/Sz8j2/39DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 9 bytes

```
{mf2f=:*}
```

Anonymous block that takes the input number from the stack and replaces it by either `1` or `0`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoAwFEXBrZzGxir3ma/gSsRChBRCwF5c@3Pmus/huzAWIolModJQQEKGFhRRQhkVVFHDwuHv6Na3df58evwH)

#### Explanation

```
{       e# Begin block
  mf    e# Array of (repeated) prime factors
  2f=   e# Compare each element of that array with 2
  :*    e# Fold product over the array
}       e# End block
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 6 bytes

```
P}2]1q
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=P%7D2%5D1q&input=16&warnings=0&hex=0)

```
P      - Prime factors.
 }     - Deduplicate.
  2]1  - Create a one-element list, [2].
     q - Is equal?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```kotlin
{it-1 xor it>it}
```

### Test

```kotlin
private val t: (Int) -> Boolean =
{it-1 xor it>it}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(t(0))
    println(t(1))
    println(t(999))
    println(t(1024))
    println(t(2))
}
```

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##ZcyxCsJAEITh3qeY8q4IJMHmgh5oZ@0TbBHD4rkn6xqUkGc/rzZTfgz/PVtiKU/lmWzETAk2wF3EPJqIc85pJMGxLGxNh09WsEW2tdzeggexONLpNeCkSt/D1ZRlih7LDnU1K5bEmWu9/5NuIyGE7avt9xvsq6zlBw)

Comment: The note saying zero handling isn't needed was added after your answer, but in light of it, `{it-2 and it<1}` is [1 byte shorter](https://tio.run/##ZcyxCsIwFIXh3ac4YzIU2uCSUgu6OfsEF6zlYryR9FqQ0mePmc0ZPw7/M2pgye/EK@mElQK0h7mKWjQjLjGGiQSnvLE2DiR3sA7dnh8fwYtYDKV56XFOib7DTRPLPFpsB5SVqmgQo6a19k@6Srz39at1xwpdkT3/AA "Kotlin – Try It Online"). I'd recommend keeping the zero-handling solution too, though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 10 bytes

```julia
!n=n-1$n>n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fMc82T9dQJc8u739afpFCnkJmnoKGgZWhgYGBJhdnZpqCYh4XJ2eeQo2dQkFRZl5JDpCbmpfCBcT/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 11 bytes

```
logBASE(Ans,2
Ans and not(fPart(Ans
```

Alternate solution (14 bytes):

```
max(Ans=2^seq(I²,I,2,Ans
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 28 bytes

```perl
$_=sprintf'%b',<>;say/^10+$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ra4oCgzryRNXTVJXcfGzro4sVI/ztBAW0X//39TQ6N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 12 bytes

```
$R:7-8⊕7>7%6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9fJcjKXNfiUddUcztzVbP//00A)

Cubically's code is quite short and easily writable, if the solution does not involves too much (more than 1) temporary variables.

Explanation: I used other people's solutions, calculate `(n^(n-1)) > n`.

```
$               Input number n, store to memory index 7.
 R              Make the cube unsolved by perform a move "R" on the cube, thus the value of face 8 will be truthy (1).
  :7            Set notepad value to value of memory index 7 (number n)
    -8          Subtract by value of memory index 8, which is 1 because cube is unsolved.
      ⊕7       Calculate bit-xor of current notepad value (n-1) with value of memory index 7 (n), store to notepad.
        >7      Calculate (notepad > n), store to notepad.
          %6    Print value of notepad as number (0 for falsy, 1 for truthy).
```

Comment: As long as an interpreter exists that your 11 byte version works in then it is valid and can be submitted as your solution.

Comment: What's wrong with TIO's Cubically?

Comment: @MDXF According to the specification when the cube is solved (initially) face 8 should be truthy (1), but it is 0. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5NykxOzMmp/P9f1eL/fwA)

Comment: Oh, that's a bug in the spec, not the language. `8` is used for looping until the cube is solved, e.g. `(R2)8` will perform R2 while the cube is *not* solved. So `8` contains 0 when the cube *is* solved and 1 when it's not. Just fixed that in the [spec](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically/wiki/Faces).

Comment: The if-else is still bugged, though. (isn't it? I didn't actually check right now)

Comment: `%6` can be shortened to `%`.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 16 bytes

```
[:|~2^a=b\_X1}?0
```

This checks all powers of 2 from 1 to the input, to see if it matches the input. Prints 1 when it does, 0 when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 12 bytes

```javascript
n=>(n^n-1)>n
```

Port of [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142579/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoAgEEDRdZ1ilooYujY9SiCmYchMaHh9s9V///bdt1Dz80qkM44EdqB1DA@UmjsciSqw7isgWFBmZget1C8h@LrkBCwx5BwCYaMSt0LXfDM@)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>22</s> 24+1 bytes

```php
<?=(($n=$argn)^$n-1)>$n;
```

Run as pipe with `-rF`. Prints `1` for truthy, empty output for falsy.

hmm ... looks like a port from Dennis´ answer.

---

Dang, @Deadcode is right: bitwise operations rank lower than comparisons.
And try as I might, I could not find a way around the parentheses.

Comment: This doesn't work: [Try it online!](https://tinyurl.com/3fkuj7wa "Bash – Try It Online") An extra pair of parentheses are needed (+2 bytes): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89TsQwEIVrcoqHZcWJVpYI2yBsh452L4BYmdghUcI48hZQUHMAjshFgh1AyxQzmp@n982TPQ1r9NZBRgchELUWx98Qq74zVcXJcBufqX7kJJu65aTWv5PCd0OAJDAemcgNeyCmBFp0wXkF/@Y77NuyUXiZ@rEPOCi8DuPscZq9X5AWLuA2Z/JJdkCJKS3C4um4jM7wS4U@RFQVyFwpkDbN9U2qux3qOuuKizMF4evjEwxtuU/meZxwsX1oobP5z9Dmi2LzfMcyLJD3G3EmUJjGeQb/j3H@RK7f "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
say!(($_=<>)&$_-2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsQwGIRf5d8QbMK20i6uh21T6qWyBy8evMhSQkltIE1CElil9OoD@Ig@iDXsIl6Gf5jhn88Kp/arNnDmTkv95iER71Y4OQkduDoc/MRdmHjox6QEY4UmbYrqI6IlnEepBKlqOvejmWzZKOatkoEkWZLiLjbkQHzPFXeNqnZ0btRrcWJR89MCg3EEy6srsazYJY3Xdktnzz@gBSyXBXplvCAt/V@vLuvNw/PjC0NH9AeyEWYglMKVhmDFqraOReukDoBViuD78wtQucbvG0JwxyL7De6yHV2Xtcju736MDdJov2ZP@9u8yH8B)

Note that this would be [**17 bytes**](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwEER/ZStEsyJ2sUPSiyXjXhxy6KWHXkowxshEsLWEZSjF@JoPyCfmQ6qKhFyGHXaYeU6PtAvW6QHrhJUHJgr4ORnSKEsxdyf77YqKlHdkJlylq4Q3MWF69F1L7ViR3Ii5oq/8qKJmxwV6OyI3d1dwI9XtG6/1Wsy@/YUauFkW6Mh6jXVse6zL23r19rH/VOzAHiBP2vYoBNxpkJOSdRmDbjTDBJwSBtfzBVgRYjsib1REf@ZNuhFhCXn6uv2zbjJ28CF9371kefYP) with swapping allowed, but by my interpretation, the challenge specifies that swapping is not allowed.

This is modification of the classic bitwise formula for powers of 2, using \$n∧(n-2)=0\$ instead of \$n∧(n-1)=0\$. It appears nobody else has used this yet? This method would work for eliminating all powers of 2 less than any chosen power of 2. For example, to eliminate \$\{1,2,4,8\}\$, the formula would be \$n∧(n-16)=0\$.

To handle zero correctly, a port of [Dennis's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142578/17216) won't work, since Perl casts the result of bitwise XOR to an unsigned integer, giving the result `18446744073709551615` for `0^-1`. This can be fixed with `use integer`, but that would result in the program being **34 bytes**:

```
use integer;say((($_=<>)^$_-1)>$_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NSsQwFEZf5VoCTZhWWnFcTJpSN5VZuHHhRsYSSjoNpElIIqOUbn0AH9EHsYYZxM3l/nxwzrXCqe2qDZy401IfPaTi3QonJ6EDV7udn7gLEw/9mFIwVmjcZkm9TwiF0yiVwFVN5n40k6WNYt4qGXCapxnqYkIO2Pdccdeo6obMjXopDyzW4rDAYBxG8jJRJCt2vsZusyGz5x/QApLLAr0yXuCW/NOrM725f3p4Zsk@@RO5EmbAhMDFBiPFqraOQeukDoBUlsD35xckdH3zAuJOHIWjkYQxRh2Lf7yiLi9JHdXXZS3yu9sfY4M02q/54/a6KItf)

There is, however, a way to have proper zero handling at **21 bytes**:

```
say!(($_=<>)--&$_)x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BasMwFESv8iNELRG7OKHpIraMu3HJopsusinBCCPXAlkSkiApxtseoEfsQeqKhNLN8IcZ/jwrnNot2sCZOy31u4dEXKxwchQ6cLXf@5G7MPLQDUkBxgpNmhRVB0QLOA9SCVJWdOoGM9qiVsxbJQNJsiTFbWzInviOK@5qVW7pVKu3zYlFzU8z9MYRLG@uwLJk1zRe6zWdPP@ABrCcZ@iU8YI09H@9vK7XT6/PR4YO6A9kJUxPKIUbDcGKlU0Vi9ZJHQCrFMH35xegYonfV4TglkX2LLuLqBfcLvOSZ48PP8YGabRfspfdfb7JfwE)

With both zero handling and consistent truthy values, **23 bytes**:

```
say!(($_=<>)&$_-2)>!-$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsQwGIRf5W8INmFb6S6uh21T6qWyBy8evMhSQkltIE1CElil9OoD@Ig@iDXsIl6Gf5jhn88Kp/arNnDmTkv95iEV71Y4OQkduDoc/MRdmHjox7QEY4UmbYbqI6IlnEepBKlqOvejmWzZKOatkoGkeZrhLjbkQHzPFXeNqnZ0btTr9sSiFqcFBuMIlldXYlmxSxqvzYbOnn9AC1guC/TKeEFa@r9eXdabh@fHF4aO6A8kEWYglMKVhmDFqraOReukDoBVhuD78wtQucbvCSG4Y5H9Bnf5jtZJjrt1WYv8/u7H2CCN9mv@tL8ttsUv)

---

Checking for a power of 2 is **18 bytes** if returning truthy for zero is acceptable:

```
say!(($_=<>)&$_-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsQwGIRf5d8QbMK20orrYduUeqnswYsHL7KUUFIbSJOQBFYpvfoAPqIPYg27yF6Gf5jhn88Kp3arNnDiTkv97iERH1Y4OQkduNrv/cRdmHjox6QEY4UmbYrqA6IlnEapBKlqOvejmWzZKOatkoEkWZLiLjbkQHzPFXeNqu7o3Ki34sii5scFBuMIlhdXYlmxcxqv7ZbOnn9CC1guC/TKeEFael2vzuvN48vTK0MH9A@yEWYglMKFhmDFqraOReukDoBViuDn6xtQucbvG0JwxyL7De6ygq7LWmQP97/GBmm0X7Pn3W1e5H8)

With proper handling of zero, it's **21 bytes**:

```
say!(($_=<>)&$_-1)*$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsQwGIRf5d8QbOK20orrYduUeqnswYsHL7KUUFIbSJOQBFYpvfoAPqIPYg27iJfhH2b457PCqd2qDZy401K/eUjEuxVOTkIHrvZ7P3EXJh76MSnBWKFJm6L6gGgJp1EqQaqazv1oJls2inmrZCBJlqS4iw05EN9zxV2jqls6N@q1OLKo@XGBwTiC5cWVWFbsnMZru6Wz5x/QApbLAr0yXpCW/q9X5/Xm4fnxhaED@gPZCDMQSuFCQ7BiVVvHonVSB8AqRfD9@QWoXOP3DSG4Y5H9CndZQa9xty5rnt3f/RgbpNF@zZ52N3mR/wI)

With both zero handling and consistent truthy values, **23 bytes**:

```
say!(($_=<>)&$_-1)>!-$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BSsQwGIRf5W8INmFbacX1sG1KvVT24MWDF1lKKKkNpElIAqssvfoAPqIPYg27yF6Gf5jhn88Kp7arNnDkTkv97iEVH1Y4OQsduNrt/MxdmHkYprQCY4UmXYaaPaIVHCepBKkbehomM9uqVcxbJQNJ8zTDfWzIkfiBK@5aVd/RU6veygOLWhwWGI0jWF5chWXNzmm8Nht68vwTOsByWWBQxgvS0et6fV5vH1@eXhnao3@QRJiRUAoXGoIVq7smFq2TOgBWGYKfr29A1Rq/J4TgnkX2G9znJW2SHPfrshb5w/2vsUEa7df8eXtblMUf)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```csharp
x=>x!=1&&x&x-1==0
```

-5 by Steffan

Comment: Instead of `false` you can use something like `0>1` (I think). However, something like `x!=1&&x&x-1==0` should work, and possibly `n^n-1>n`. (I don't know C# well).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize I could do it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
ĐĦ1=*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIQjywxttf7/NwAA)

Outputs 0 if not completely even, n if completely even

```
Đ            implicit input (n); duplicate on stack
 Ħ           get Hamming weight
  1=         equal to 1?
    *        coerce boolean to integer and multiply by n; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
&-Í
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSE&code=Ji3N&input=MTY) or [test numbers 0-16](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=VQ&code=Ji3N&footer=IntzIPoyfSAtPiB7IVY&input=MTcgLW1S)

This is `n & -(2 - n)` (simplifying to `n & n-2`), with the `!` flag negating the result (0 becomes true, everything else becomes false)

Comment: Nice use of the auto-insertion of the second `U` :) I'd probably not have thought to try it after the `&-`, opting instead for `&Ín`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 7 bytes

```
<[XOR<:
```

Uses \$n < (n \oplus n - 1)\$.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmux3CY6wj_IxgrCu5miyZWanJGvoJ6XX6KQnJ9bkJNakppTqZBalpoHMUPJSiENaIihgiGQMFIwNFEwtIDqwVAPAnA9RgpApWZAPRYQuxYsgNAA)

```
<[XOR<:
     <:  NB. decrement
 [       NB. input
  XOR    NB. XOR
<        NB. is n less than result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
←2D≡
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FisetU0wcnnUuXBJcVJyMVRwwQ4jLhMuQzMuQyMLLkMDIMVlCOQD2RB5AA)

```
←2D≡
←       Decrement
 2D     Convert to base 2
   ≡    Check if all digits are equal
```

Answer (score 1):

## Sed, 117 bytes

Not the obvious language for an arithmetic code-golf, but still fun:

```
:a
s/^0*2$/T/
s/.*[,0]$/F/
t
s/[13579]/&,/g
y/123456789/011223344/
s/,0/5/g
s/,1/6/g
s/,2/7/g
s/,3/8/g
s/,4/9/g
ta
ba
```

This works using successive division by 2, terminating when we reach 2 (true) or a value that ends in zero (which must be a multiple of 5, or zero itself) or with a carry-out from having divided an odd number.

In more detail:

```
:a                   # start of loop
s/^0*2$/T/           # reached 2
s/.*[,0]$/F/         # reached an odd number
t                    # in which case, jump to end

s/[13579]/&,/g          # odd numbers cause a carry when divided
y/123456789/011223344/  # divide by two

s/,0/5/g             # add the carry
s/,1/6/g
s/,2/7/g
s/,3/8/g
s/,4/9/g

ta                   # jump, clearing the "substituted" flag
ba                   # jump anyway
```

Sample input and corresponding output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
32
64
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

```
F
F
T
F
T
T
T
T
```

(that last value is 2¹⁰⁰⁰)

Answer (score 0):

#### C, 31 bytes

```
f(x){return !(x&(x-1))&&!(x-1)}
```

These are the powers of 2, except 1, and thus binary arithmetics solves the problem.

Comment: All submissions must be either full programs or functions. In particular, assuming that the input is stored in a certain variable is not allowed. Also, this approach fails when **x = 1**, which is a power of two but not.completely even.

Comment: @Dennis 1) Ok, I did, bit now I lost a lot of bytes. 2) The task still only describes the powers of 2, except 1. 3) What it with the languages on which no functions and procedures exist? 4) If you accept functions and programs, why you don't accept *expressions*? An expression in C is an independently calculatable execution fragment, just as the programs and the functions. | I am so sad, my solution is already a dirty one, it lacks already the katra.

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 29 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P00jT9M2IzE3NzMvvTw1Mz2jBCRga6ibp2pk/T8tv0gj09ZAR8HEUkehoCgzr0QjU0dBSUFJRyFNI1NTU9P6PwA)

```
f(n)=hammingweight(n)==1-n%2;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 43 Bytes

```python
import math
lambda x:math.log(x,2)%1or x==1
```

Outputs false for completely even number and outputs a truthy value for not completely even number.

[Try it online (2 bytes added to allow testing)](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCE3sSSDK802JzE3KSVRocIKxNfLyU/XqNAx0lQ1zC9SqLC1NfxfUJSZV6KRpgEiM/MKSks0NIHgv5GZkaGJCQA)

Completely even numbers are just powers of 2 excluding 1. This programme takes the binary logarithm of the number. This only gives an integer when the argument is a power of 2. The modulo is to check if it is an integer.

Comment: Was this downvote from before this was deleted? If not, then why is it there?

Comment: Per [the timeline](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/261282/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries), the downvote was indeed from before the answer was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 21 bytes

Requirement: 2's complement arithmetic

```c
f(x){return!(x&x-2);}
```

This is a minor modification of the well-known expression `x & (x-1)` which yields zero when `x` is an power of two (including 2⁰, i.e. unity).  By subtracting an additional 1 from the right-hand side, we exclude the value that has that bit set.

0 results in a true value; if we wish to exclude that, we need an extra 3 bytes: `!(x&x-2)&&x`.

---

### Demo

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = INT_MAX;  i > 0; --i) {
        if (f(i)) { printf("%d\n", i); }
    }
}
```

The demo produces this output on a 32-bit system:

```
1073741824
536870912
268435456
134217728
67108864
33554432
16777216
8388608
4194304
2097152
1048576
524288
262144
131072
65536
32768
16384
8192
4096
2048
1024
512
256
128
64
32
16
8
4
2
```